# Using Prototype's Class.create to define private/protected properties and methods

Tags: javascript, oop, private, prototypejs, protected

There is a good generalized method for defining private and protected properties and methods in Javascript, [here on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611/javascript-private-methods). However, the current version of Prototype (1.6.0) doesn't have a built-in way to define them through its [`Class.create()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance) syntax.

I'm curious what the best practices are when developers want to define private and protected properties and methods when using Prototype. Is there a better way than the generic one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is using local variables in your constructor function (initialize) for prototype and then creating a closure that will access/expose this variable to your public methods.

Here's a code example:

```
// properties are directly passed to `create` method
var Person = Class.create({
   initialize: function(name) {
      // Protected variables
      var _myProtectedMember = 'just a test';

      this.getProtectedMember = function() {
         return _myProtectedMember;
      }

      this.name = name;
   },
   say: function(message) {
      return this.name + ': ' + message + this.getProtectedMember();
   }
});
```

Here's Douglas crockford theory on the subject.

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I voted up TML's answer as well, since the link he includes has a full discussion on this topic, and reveals why other (cleaner-looking) implementations don't work.

Comment: @SleepyCod : how would you define a totally encapsulated private variable, that is, one that does not have a setter or getter? Your example has a getter so other class methods can get the field, but that exposes the field to the outside world.

Comment: @Christophe Eblé This is not a private method. Use var getProtectedMember = function(){... However, it is then not possible to access this method from within other methods, but at least it cannot be accessed from outside the class. I am researching if it is possible to allow a method to be accessible from within but not outside...

Answer (score 2):

There's a discussion [here](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/152-implement-private-variables-for-classes) in Prototype's lighthouse that shows that explains why you can't get this effect with Prototype's Class.create.

Comment: Can you give me access to this link? I agree with your opinion but I would like to see the discussion, but it requires a login. It would not allow me to use my Google login...

Comment: [Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20081204014823/http://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/152-implement-private-variables-for-classes)  is a link to the discussion as captured by archive.org.

Comment: Thanks. This is a very interesting discussion. I would love to see this implemented. I have had a detailed look at the patch, and it looks pretty solid. I will do some testing with the patch merged into prototype-1.7.3.js and see if this is reliable...

Answer (score 0):

The key is to add the public methods as closures, as in the example below:

```
 Bird = Class.create (Abstract,(function () {
    var string = "...and I have wings"; //private instance member
    var secret = function () {
        return string;
    } //private instance method
    return {
        initialize: function (name) {
            this.name = name;
        }, //constructor method
        say: function (message) {
            return this.name + " says: " + message + secret();
        } //public method
    }
})());

Owl = Class.create (Bird, {
    say: function ($super, message) {
        return $super(message) + "...tweet";
    } //public method
})

var bird = new Bird("Robin"); //instantiate
console.log(bird.say("tweet")); //public method call

var owl = new Owl("Barnie"); //instantiate
console.log(owl.say("hoot")); //public method call inherit & add
```