# calling private functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make private functions in Javascript. Here is my code:

```
function Person() {
  this.id = 5;
};

Person.prototype = {
  getId: function() {
    return this.id;
  },
  walk: function() {
    alert("i am private");
  },
  eat: function() {
    alert("i am public");
  }
};
```

I want to make `walk` function *private* one and `eat` function is *public* .

Comment: What are your definitions of `private` and `public` ?

Comment: private one cant be accessed outside class even by making object while we can access public one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I mimic access modifiers in JavaScript with the Prototype library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958216/how-do-i-mimic-access-modifiers-in-javascript-with-the-prototype-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no constructions in JavaScript to define real private methods for class, but you can do so:

```
var Person = (function () {
    var Person = function () {
        this.id = 5;
    };

    var walk = function () {
        alert("i am private");
    };

    Person.prototype = {
        constructor: Person,
        getId: function (){
            return this.id;
        },
        eat: function () {
            alert("i am public");
        }
    };

    return Person;
}());
```