# How to set/ edit a property of an object by using setter

Tags: javascript

According to my research, I decided using getter/setter for my global variables(please correct me if I am wrong). I can set and get the private variable, but how can I edit value of a property in the object?

Since I no longer can use `obj.id = "33"`, I tried `obj.id.set("33")` which makes no sense. How can I edit a value in the object?

```js
var x = {"id":"93","customId":"a1a8d3c5af2d4807879e5fc6721d65ad","accountNumber":null};

var obj = (function() {
 var holder = "";
 return {
  get: function() {
   return holder;
  },
  set: function(val) {
   holder = val;
  }
 };
})();
console.log("before setting: ", obj.get());
obj.set(x);
console.log("after setting" ,obj.get());
//obj.id = "33";
// or
// obj.id.set("33");
//console.log("new id: ", obj.get());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, you must get that object before changing its value:

```
obj.get().id = 33;
```

Comment: Makes sense. But is it safe? Can it be editable from 3rd party tools, or hackers?

Comment: here safety depends upon the access, you will provide to `obj`. Read this to get insight of access modifeir. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958216/how-do-i-mimic-access-modifiers-in-javascript-with-the-prototype-library