# Add other functions later to a class without using .prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, function, methods

How do I **reference to all functions added to the class, after the class has been built**? (Possibly as a array) and without using `prototype`.

I have built a class `foo()`, and would like to add the functionality to add new functions
that can be used later.

```
var f = new foo();
```

then

```
f.addfunc('bar',function(){/*code*/});
```

so that `f.bar();` can be used later.

Exporting (?) functions by using `foo.__func_expose(funcname , function );` does not work.
(probably I am doing it the wrong way.) There seems to be a error. (see code below for detail).

The aim is to have an array containing all the functions added and the actual functions, so it can be called/replaced later.

Is it even feasible in javascript to expose new function names from within a public function?

I would like to achieve something along the line of

```
var MyExtendedFoo = foo();
MyExtendedFoo.__func_add("bar",(function (a, b){
    alert('called : anon-func-we-named-bar'); return 2+a+b;}));
MyExtendedFoo.bar(1,3); // <---this does not work.
    // It should alert a message, then return 6.
```

The actual code at the moment is

```
function foo(){
  // we store reference to ourself in __self
  this.__self = arguments.callee;
  var self = arguments.callee;

  // array that holds funcname , function
  if (!self.__func_list_fname) self.__func_list_fname = [];
  if (!self.__func_list_func) self.__func_list_func = [];

  // allow foo.__func_expose(); register to public
  self['__func_expose'] = function(){
    var self = __self;
    for(var i=0;i<self.__func_list_fname.length;i++){
      self[''+self.__func_list_fname[i]+''] = self.__func_list_func[i];
     // <---This part seems wrong. How do I do it?
    };
  return __self.__func_return();
  };

  // allow foo.__func_add( funcname , function );
  self['__func_add'] = function(f,v){
    var self = __self;
    self.__func_list_fname.push(f);
    self.__func_list_func.push(v);
    // tell itself to expose the new func as well as the old ones.
    return __self.__func_expose();
  };

  // build obj from known list and return it.
  self['__func_return'] = function(){
    var self = __self;
    var obj = {};
    obj['__func_expose'] = self['__func_expose'];
    obj['__func_add'] = self['__func_add'];
    obj['__func_return'] = self['__func_return'];
    for(var i=0;i<self.__func_list_fname.length;i++){
      obj[''+self.__func_list_fname[i]+''] = self.__func_list_func[i];
    };
    return obj;
  };
  // Return ourself so we can chain
  return self.__func_return();
}
```

Yes. I have done my homework. I am still missing something.

- http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript
- http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/55611/javascript-private-methods

@philgiese frameworks are nice, but here we want to avoid dependency, and keep it lightweight.
Besides, there's no **fun** to it, is there :-) Don't get me wrong, I have nothing against using prototype.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that's different from `var f = new foo(); f.bar = function() { ... };` ???

Comment: And why do you want to avoid `prototype`?

Comment: Fair question. I need a array representing the functions that has been added. So `foo.__func_add('bar', ... ).__func_add('doe', ... )...` And later in life, `foo.RetAllFuncAdded()` or such will return `['bar','doe', ... ]`.

Comment: Philgiese won't be noticed of your comment; you should add it (as a comment) to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the comment of @Pointy you are missing a `this` when you are assigning `__self` to `var self`. As I read the code `__self` is a variable of your `foo` object, so you have to reference it as `this.__self` when you use it.

And by the way, why aren't you using any framework for this? When I remember correctly the Prototype framework offers such functionality.

**EDIT**:
Just looked it up for you. This function should exactly do, what you want. [AddMethods](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/class/prototype/addmethods/)

Comment: In `foo()`,`__self` is setup as `this.__self = arguments.callee;`  So `__self` becomes the function that is currently executing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee    
So `self.whatever` _should_ be like `foo.whatever` ... hopefully. Should I fix it ?

Comment: *EDIT* : when replaced with `var self = this.__self` whole thing breaks apart with error `self is undefined`...

Comment: Ok, if you do this.__self inside the other function you loose scope. But why aren't you using some framework? Any reason for this?