# What does 'var that = this;' mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, this

In a JavaScript file I saw:

```
function Somefunction(){
   var that = this; 
   ... 
}
```

What is the purpose of declaring `that` and assigning `this` this to it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [var self = this?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/337878/1048572)

Comment: The "this" and "that" hack is not required for arrow functions. With arrow functions "this" works as expected.
See here for more details [ES6 In Depth: Arrow functions](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/)

Comment: here concept of this is explained https://scotch.io/@alZami/understanding-this-in-javascript

Comment: A great explanation on mysterious this behavior based on context [here](https://zellwk.com/blog/this/)

Comment: Latest & updated explanation can be found [here](https://medium.com/@VoyagerSukrit/var-me-this-in-javascript-65fee9d7a8f8)

Comment: @Bergi I don't think you realized he was asking about "that" not "self"

Comment: @TrevorBlythe I did realise it, and was linking the other question because it is exactly the same topic. If there were questions about `var _this = this;` or `var $this = this;` we'd still close them as duplicates; the variable name does not matter.

Comment: @TrevorBlythe Admittedly, [What underlies this JavaScript idiom: `var self = this`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/962033/1048572) would be an even better duplicate target (if judging by age).

Answer (score 521, accepted):

I'm going to begin this answer with an illustration:

```
var colours = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
document.getElementById('element').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // this is a reference to the element clicked on

    var that = this;

    colours.forEach(function() {
        // this is undefined
        // that is a reference to the element clicked on
    });
});
```

My answer originally demonstrated this with jQuery, which is only very slightly different:

```
$('#element').click(function(){
    // this is a reference to the element clicked on

    var that = this;

    $('.elements').each(function(){
        // this is a reference to the current element in the loop
        // that is still a reference to the element clicked on
    });
});
```

Because `this` frequently changes when you change the scope by calling a new function, you can't access the original value by using it.  Aliasing it to `that` allows you still to access the original value of `this`.

Personally, I dislike the use of `that` as the alias.  It is rarely obvious what it is referring to, especially if the functions are longer than a couple of lines. I *always* use a more descriptive alias.  In my examples above, I'd probably use `clickedEl`.

Comment: I usually go with `var self = this;`. The word `that` seems to imply the variable is anything BUT `this`.

Comment: @David Yes I've thought **that** is somewhat misleading. But if, as Crockford says, it's a convention, is it wise to go down that route. I totally agree with you though, makes much more sense.

Comment: @David:  These were my thoughts, var that = this and I am wondering what is that?  If implementation used self, I probably would not have even wondered.

Comment: @El Ronnoco, but "He's got gray hair and a scraggly beard and his manner brings to mind a grumpy old man who yells at kids to get off of his lawn." - http://blogging.compendiumblog.com/blog/software-for-humans/0/0/on-becoming-a-douglas-crockford-fanboy

    ;-p

Comment: I was just watching [this video](http://blog.mozilla.com/dherman/2011/02/23/my-js-meetup-talk/) on EcmaScript.next and the presenter, dherman from Mozilla, refers to javascript's `this` scoping issue as "the `var self = this;` trick". Interestingly, with the new function literal syntax `this` will be lexically bound; e.g., `function Node(){ var self = this; this.children.forEach(#(child){ console.log(this === self); /* true! */ });}` where `#` is the new syntax.

Comment: So in this new function literal syntax how would you get the this for the child?

Comment: I'd use something like `clickedEl`, too.

Comment: @ElRonnoco: That's an appeal to authority, though. If we only ever do what "the famous people" say we should do, we're headed for disaster.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well I wouldn't describe crockford as famous! I'm not proposing we take Kim Kardashian's advice on JavaScript conventions. However Crockford does know what he's talking about when it comes to JS. He certainly outranks me, I can't speak on anyone else behalf. And his website could certainly use an update, it's bloody awful! :)

Comment: @DavidMurdoch Once caveat to using `self` is that in most browser implementations, [`window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.self) is an environment-set global variable. Shadowing `self` with a local variable might break third-party scripts that expect to have global access to the browser-set `self` attribute of `window`. In practice, of course, this is rarely a problem.

Comment: @apsillers, that is just not true. It could only happen if you were inlining the 3rd party script directly within the function that assigns `self` to `this`; at which point it is no longer third party - you have complete control over the code.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch Agreed -- it wouldn't be a problem with any sensible plugin architecture. It would be better to say that shadowing of `self` could be (theoretically) problematic if you're maintaining some extant code you didn't write. A full discussion of whether or not my concern is valid as a legitimate "best practice" lies in the scope of Programmers.SE, so I won't try to fully justify it here; rather, I'll simply let it stand as an extant concern with admittedly remote probability.

Comment: I dislike the choice to use jQuery for the example. A simple Array.forEach sample would show the problem all the same and not involve any libraries.

Comment: @Jasper Indeed. I would have do that if i were writing the answer today, and in fact I'll add it to the answer. In 2011 `Array.forEach` was not in widespread use.

Comment: Ah yes, I do remember when you had to add that function to the array prototype for browser compatibility.

Comment: The `forEach` function takes a second optional argument is which is the binding of the function. `colours.forEach(function(){/* 'this' is bound correctly --> */}, this);` So a note should be added that `var that = this` isn't _actually_ needed with `forEach`.

Comment: In the first foreach 'this' is undefined, and in the second one its not. Why?

Comment: @user5539357 Because that's how forEach works. That's simply how the language specification defines it. My guess is that this was done to avoid ambiguity/confusion.

Answer (score 117):

From [Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html)

> By convention, we make a private **that**
>   variable. This is used to make the
>   object available to the private
>   methods. This is a workaround for an
>   error in the ECMAScript Language
>   Specification which causes **this** to be
>   set incorrectly for inner functions.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03fo91mL/)

```
function usesThis(name) {
    this.myName = name;

    function returnMe() {
        return this;        //scope is lost because of the inner function
    }

    return {
        returnMe : returnMe
    }
}

function usesThat(name) {
    var that = this;
    this.myName = name;

    function returnMe() {
        return that;            //scope is baked in with 'that' to the "class"
    }

    return {
        returnMe : returnMe
    }
}

var usesthat = new usesThat('Dave');
var usesthis = new usesThis('John');
alert("UsesThat thinks it's called " + usesthat.returnMe().myName + '\r\n' +
      "UsesThis thinks it's called " + usesthis.returnMe().myName);
```

This alerts...

> UsesThat thinks it's called Dave
>
> UsesThis thinks it's called undefined

Comment: Thanks, sums it up well enough for me.

Comment: I read that, did not understand because it had no detail, searched on Google, found this page. Where I am again pointed to the same sentence. Hence the downvote.

Comment: That's a fair point, I would say that someone unfamiliar with JavaScript would have difficulty grasping the concept from my answer alone. I did answer very briefly (and I did link to the page you Googled for..) I'd say lonesomeday's answer is the clearest, though I would still have preferred it in plain JS as opposed to a jQuery example.

Comment: :) I am glad you took no offence. Here's a cookie, please have a nice day good sir!

Comment: I take no offence. It's nice to see someone who comments when downvoting!

Comment: The problem with Crockford's answer is the `that` variable isn't used in his example at all. It makes it look as though just creating a variable holding `this` does something to the rest of the code.

Comment: I never realised that needing to do this was down to an error in the spec! I mean, it's a bit annoying to need to do it but I thought there would be a real reason.

Comment: I **always** thought that `this` not working in private functions was intended behaviour. If this "bug" was fixed and still worked as expected, it'd make a lot of code more readable and a lot of coders happy.

Comment: @r3m0t, so using "that" wasn't made to be taken literally?

Comment: @eflat no, it's a misnomer really. I think it may have been adopted because it is a similar looking word (4 chars, starts with t) - but of course from an English perspective *this* is considered separate from *that*, rather than synonymous. I use **self**, I think this may be becoming more common now.

Comment: Your example looks like what I was looking for and after deep research, I just figured that `this` is losing its scope because `returnMe` is being returned in an object `return { returnMe }`. However, if you had to bind `returnMe` as in this.returnMe = returnMe; `this` wouldn't lose its scope because of implicit biding to your created object.

Comment: Here is an example 
 ```function usesThis(name) {
    this.myName = name;
    const that = this;
    function returnMe() {
        console.log('this: ', this) //scope is lost because of the inner function and refers to the returned object
        return that.myName;        
    }

    return {
        myName: 'I am not on that :)',
        returnMe
    }
}```

Answer (score 91):

This is a hack to make inner functions (functions defined inside other functions) work more like they should. In javascript when you define one function inside another `this` automatically gets set to the global scope. This can be confusing because you expect `this` to have the same value as in the outer function.

```
var car = {};
car.starter = {};

car.start = function(){
    var that = this;

    // you can access car.starter inside this method with 'this'
    this.starter.active = false;

    var activateStarter = function(){
        // 'this' now points to the global scope
        // 'this.starter' is undefined, so we use 'that' instead.
        that.starter.active = true;

        // you could also use car.starter, but using 'that' gives
        // us more consistency and flexibility
    };

    activateStarter();

};
```

This is specifically a problem when you create a function as a method of an object (like `car.start` in the example) then create a function inside that method (like `activateStarter`). In the top level method `this` points to the object it is a method of (in this case, `car`) but in the inner function `this` now points to the global scope. This is a pain.

Creating a variable to use by convention in both scopes is a solution for this very general problem with javascript (though it's useful in jquery functions, too). This is why the very general sounding name `that` is used. It's an easily recognizable convention for overcoming a shortcoming in the language.

Like El Ronnoco hints at [Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/) thinks this is a good idea.

Comment: I suppose this is more useful answer than accepted one. Because it clarifies the reason why Crockford has invented "that" while answer about jQuery doesn't.

Comment: This is actually a better example then the accepted answer. It explains what it's like as a "an error in the ECMAScript Language Specification which causes this to be set incorrectly for inner functions" said by Douglas.

Comment: You may want to make it grammar correct though. I know it's more like a typo, but it could confuse javascript beginners as this question is more beginner like. I mean it should be: var car = {}; car.starter = {};car.start = function(){...}

Answer (score 11):

The use of `that` is not really necessary if you make a workaround with the use of `call()` or `apply()`:

```
var car = {};
car.starter = {};

car.start = function(){
    this.starter.active = false;

    var activateStarter = function(){
        // 'this' now points to our main object
        this.starter.active = true;
    };

    activateStarter.apply(this);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes `this` can refer to another scope and refer to something else, for example suppose you want to call a constructor method inside a DOM event, in this case `this` will refer to the DOM element not the created object.

HTML

```
<button id="button">Alert Name</button>
```

JS

```
var Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  var that = this;
  this.sayHi = function() {
    alert(that.name);
  };
};

var ahmad = new Person('Ahmad');
var element = document.getElementById('button');
element.addEventListener('click', ahmad.sayHi); // => Ahmad
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/degaja/1/)

The solution above will assing `this` to `that` then we can and access the name property inside the `sayHi` method from `that`, so this can be called without issues inside the DOM call.

Another solution is to assign an empty `that` object and add properties and methods to it and then return it. But with this solution you lost the `prototype` of the constructor.

```
var Person = function(name) {
  var that = {};
  that.name = name;
  that.sayHi = function() {
    alert(that.name);
  };
  return that;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example
 `

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var lastItem = null;
        $(".our-work-group > p > a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var item = $(this).html(); //Here value of "this" is ".our-work-group > p > a"
            if (item == lastItem) {
                lastItem = null;
                $('.our-work-single-page').show();
            } else {
                lastItem = item;
                $('.our-work-single-page').each(function() {
                    var imgAlt = $(this).find('img').attr('alt'); //Here value of "this" is '.our-work-single-page'. 
                    if (imgAlt != item) {
                        $(this).hide();
                    } else {
                        $(this).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });`
```

So you can see that value of this is two different values depending on the DOM element you target but when you add "that" to the code above you change the value of "this" you are targeting.

```
`$(document).ready(function() {
        var lastItem = null;
        $(".our-work-group > p > a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var item = $(this).html(); //Here value of "this" is ".our-work-group > p > a"
            if (item == lastItem) {
                lastItem = null;
                var that = this;
                $('.our-work-single-page').show();
            } else {
                lastItem = item;
                $('.our-work-single-page').each(function() {
                   ***$(that).css("background-color", "#ffe700");*** //Here value of "that" is ".our-work-group > p > a"....
                    var imgAlt = $(this).find('img').attr('alt'); 
                    if (imgAlt != item) {
                        $(this).hide();
                    } else {
                        $(this).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });`
```

.....***$(that).css("background-color", "#ffe700");*** //Here value of "that" is ".our-work-group > p > a" because the value of var that = this; so even though we are at "this"= '.our-work-single-page', still we can use "that" to manipulate previous DOM element.