# Javascript scope question: Can't change element via 'this' obj passed to function, but I can using longhand approach

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, this, scoping

REVISED QUESTION (SEE BELOW FOR ORIGINAL):

Here is an example of a simple ajax load with an event binding on an element within the loaded content:

soTest.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>   

        <script>
            function changeBG(obj)
                {               
                    alert('Color 1: Should Turn Red');
                    jQuery(obj).css('background-color','red');
                    alert('Color 2: Should Turn Green');
                    jQuery('#' + jQuery(obj).attr('id')).css('background-color','green');

                }

            jQuery(document).ready(
                function() {

                    jQuery('.loadedContent').load('soTest2.htm');

                    jQuery('body').delegate("#theElem","click",
                        function(){

                            var obj = this;

                            jQuery('.loadedContent').load('soTest2.htm',
                                function(){
                                    changeBG(obj);                      
                                }
                            );

                        });

                }
            );

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>  
        <div class="loadedContent">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ajax loaded content, soTest2.htm:

```
<div id="theElem" >
    Hello
</div>
```

So why is it that this doesn't work:

```
jQuery(obj).css('background-color','red');
```

But this does:

```
jQuery('#' + jQuery(obj).attr('id')).css('background-color','red');
```

---

++++++++++ORIGINAL QUESTION:++++++++++

I have a table that I want to sort when specific table headings are clicked (those with the class "sort").
For instance:

```
<a href="##" class="sort" sortby="LOCATION" direction="asc">Location</a>
```

To do that I have this code:

```
jQuery('body').delegate("click", ".sort", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    jQuery('.searchResults').html('<div align="center" style="margin-top:35px;"><img src="/common/images/ajax-loader_big.gif" /></div>');

    var TimeStamp = new Date().getTime();
    var sortItem = this;

    jQuery('.searchResults').load('modules/configSearchResultsOutput.cfm?' + TimeStamp + '&sortby=' + jQuery(this).attr('sortby') + '&direction=' + jQuery(this).attr('direction'), {
        data: jQuery('#results').val()
    }, function() {
        sortCallback(sortItem);

    });
});
```

So on the click event for one of these sortable column headings I'm storing the entire 'this' scope in a var to pass through to this function.

To simplify the question I'll just say that we're trying to change the background color of the clicked element based on the custom attr 'direction' I'm using:

```
function sortCallback(obj) {

    //Returns correct attribute value                           
    alert('In Callback: ' + jQuery(obj).attr('direction'));

    //Does not return correct attribute value -- almost like it's cached or something
    alert('Long hand reference: ' + jQuery('.sort[sortby="' + jQuery(obj).attr('sortby') + '"]').attr('direction'));

    //Must reference value via (obj) to get correct updated value
    if (jQuery(obj).attr('direction') == 'asc') {

        //Changing a value within the element via this longhand approach works
        jQuery('.sort[sortby="' + jQuery(obj).attr('sortby') + '"]').css('background-color', 'red');


        //Changing a value within the element via this shorter approach does not work                       
        jQuery(obj).css('background-color', 'red');

    }
    else {
        //Works
        jQuery('.sort[sortby="' + jQuery(obj).attr('sortby') + '"]').css('background-color', 'green');

        //Doesn't work
        jQuery(obj).css('background-color', 'green');

    }



}
```

I'm assuming I'm not understanding some aspect of javascript scoping (understanding 'this' has been very elusive to me).

Question summarized:

If I'm passing a var'd 'this' scope to a function why can't I change the aspects of the 'this' element, why must I drill down using the long way to change them?

A tricky question for me to articulate, hopefully I did a good enough job.

Thanks!

Comment: See this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript

Comment: Can you post some sample HTML here or to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? I suspect `obj` is not actually the sort link.

Comment: I revised the question, hope it's a little more clear.  I kept the original question there in case someone saw anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your ajax call replaces the DOM element.  obj refers to a DOM element that was in the DOM before you called `.load`, but was replaced.  Another element with the same ID does exist, though!  That's the one you're referring to with your 'longhand' method.

Comment: Ahhhhhh yes, it makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because that load call is asynchronous, causing jQuery to get confused. Put your code inside a callback for `load` and it should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.loadedContent').load('soTest2.htm',
    function(resp, status, xhr){
        jQuery("#theElem").bind('click',
        function(){
            changeBG(this);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: it's not jQ that's confused, it's that @Paul is holding a reference to a DOM element that's not in the document anymore.  =)