# Problem with "this" in JS

Tags: javascript, module, this

Consider the following code:

```
    var table = function () {

        return {
            _init: function (tableId) {
                this.tableId = tableId;
                this.table = $("#" + tableId);
            },

            removeStripes: function() {
                this.table.find(".alt").removeClass("alt");
            },

            addStripes: function () {
                this.table.find("tbody tr:even").addClass("alt");
            },

            resetStripes: function() {
                this.removeStripes();
                this.addStripes();
            },

            sort: function (options) {
                this.table.tablesorter(options);
                this.table.bind("sortEnd", this.resetStripes);
            },

        }

    }

var newTable = new table();
newTable._init("tableId");
var options = {};
newTable.sort(options);
```

The browser says this.removeStripes called by this.resetStripes, on one of the last lines) is not a function. I guess there is some error with `this`, but I can't figure out where it is. Any idea, anyone?

Comment: You might find an answer if you study [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript)...

Comment: A general suggestion: Add console.log statements (or alert statements, if you prefer) inside each function saying the name of the function and what it thinks "this" is.

Comment: Also, you may want to use prototype. (I'm working on a fiddle, I'll update in a few minutes with details.)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/miriam/ePWBP/3/

tablesorter is not defined in the code snippet you've provided.

Comment: I think you are using "new" in a way that is not necessary. In your case you could create a table object like this : var newTable = table();

Comment: tablesorter is included in the code somewhere else. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing coma (,) after declaration of sort function. This will probably not solve your problem, but it will 'compile' under ie<7.

Answer (score 0):

As you are declaring methods with anonymous functions, `this` is not anymore in the `table` function scope.

You should use:

```
 removeStripes: function() {
   // ...
 }.bind(this)
```

on all of your methods.

Comment: Yes, I am sure there are some variable scope issues. However, bind(this) didn't help too much...

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is a constructor method/pattern. 
Now when you call one of the instantiated objects methods (eg. newTable.removeStripes() ) the context (this) is set to newTable. I believe you can always change the context however with newTable.removeStripes.call(someOtherTableOrObject) which comes in handy in a lot of cases.

```
function Table(tableId) {

    this.tableId = tableId;
    this.table = $("#" + tableId);

    this.removeStripes = function() {
        this.table.find(".alt").removeClass("alt");
    };

    this.addStripes = function () {
        this.table.find("tbody tr:even").addClass("alt");
    };

    this.resetStripes = function() {
        this.removeStripes();
        this.addStripes();
    };

    this.sort = function (options) {
        this.table.tablesorter(options);
        this.table.bind("sortEnd", this.resetStripes);
    };

}

var newTable = new Table("tableId");
var options = {};
newTable.sort(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = function (tableId) {

        this.tableId = tableId;
        this.table = $("#" + tableId);

        this.removeStripes= function() {
            this.table.find(".alt").removeClass("alt");
        };

        this.addStripes= function () {
            this.table.find("tbody tr:even").addClass("alt");
        };

        this.resetStripes= function() {
            this.removeStripes();
            this.addStripes();
        };

        this.sort= function (options) {
            this.table.tablesorter(options);
            this.table.bind("sortEnd", this.resetStripes);
        };
}
```

The "this" keyword usage in Javascript is rather different than in other languages. The version above should work (I tested it with jsc, rather than properly in a browser with jQuery).
Now the function is a proper constructor, making the interpreter to set "this" to the object to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var table = function () {
        var that = this;
        return {
            _init: function (tableId) {
                that.tableId = tableId;
                that.table = $("#" + tableId);
            },

            removeStripes: function() {
                that.table.find(".alt").removeClass("alt");
            },

            addStripes: function () {
                that.table.find("tbody tr:even").addClass("alt");
            },

            resetStripes: function() {
                that.removeStripes();
                that.addStripes();
            },

            sort: function (options) {
                that.table.tablesorter(options);
                that.table.bind("sortEnd", that.resetStripes);
            },

        }

    }

var newTable = new table();
newTable._init("tableId");
var options = {};
newTable.sort(options);
```

Its a common pattern in JavaScript to save the `this` into another variable so you can reference it in deeper nested functions. As javascript `this` always refers to either the global object or the this object that was passed to the function through .call or .apply it's rather unreliable to use at times..