# javascript singleton scope problems with "this"

Tags: javascript, scope, this

Hi i am beginning using the singleton javascript design pattern, but i have some scope problems. Here i am just experimenting with a small ajax, retrieve and store singleton.
From within a function in the singleton i call another function (this.ready, called when the ajax has retrieved and stored the data) but it seems "this" doesn't refer to the singleton, rather it refers to "*Object #XMLHttpRequest*" according to chrome debugger, firefox just says it's undefined.

```
            var mag = {
                magObj: [], // object to store the retrieved json data

                getData: function(){
                    request = getHTTPObject(), // defined externally
                    request.onreadystatechange = this.setData;
                    request.open("POST", "be.php", true);
                    request.send(null);
                },

                setData: function(){  
                    if (request.readyState == 4)
                    {
                        this.magObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                        this.ready(); // this line yields the error, seems "this" does not refer to the singleton

                    }
                    else if (request.readyState == 1)
                    {

                    }
                },

                ready: function() {
                    console.log('ready');
                },

                construct: function(){
                    this.getData();
                },  
            }
```

Also if i try to declare the getHTTPObject() as a singleton variable in the top, instead of using global variable i get the error *Cannot read property 'readyState' of undefined*. Again it's "this" getHTTPObject that seems to be undefined even though i set it at the top:

```
        var mag = {
            magObj: [],
            request: getHTTPObject(),

            getData: function(){

                this.request.onreadystatechange = this.setData;
                this.request.open("POST", "be.php", true);
                this.request.send(null);
            },

            setData: function(){  
                if (this.request.readyState == 4) // debugger says this.request is undefined
                {
                    this.magObj = JSON.parse(this.request.responseText);

                }
                else if (this.request.readyState == 1)
                {

                }
            },

            construct: function(){
                this.getData();
            },  
        }
```

Comment: "this" changes in javascript according to the calling function. Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a singleton you could try

```
           var mag = {
            magObj: [], // object to store the retrieved json data

            getData: function(){
                request = getHTTPObject(), // defined externally
                request.onreadystatechange = this.setData;
                request.open("POST", "be.php", true);
                request.send(null);
            },

            setData: function(){  
                if (request.readyState == 4)
                {
                    this.magObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    mag.ready(); // this line yields the error, seems "this" does not refer to the singleton

                }
                else if (request.readyState == 1)
                {

                }
            },

            ready: function() {
                console.log('ready');
            },

            construct: function(){
                this.getData();
            },  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**#1**
`setData` is a callback function for the `XMLHttpRequest` object. It's therefore run in the scope of the `XMLHttpRequest` object. Use `mag` instead of `this`.

**#2**
Same as `#1`: `this` refers to the `XMLHttpRequest`, rather than you `mag` variable.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the scope problem, you need to use the concepts of closures in javascript. basically a scope where functions have access to properties and methods in the context that created that function.. ok for a more clear explanation.. try initializing your mag object as a function..

```
var mag = function(){
    var magObj = [];
    var getData = function(){
        //here you'll have access to the magObj collection
    };
}
```

The previous is a classic example of a javascript closure..
Of course you instantiate the mag object simply as a function invocation **mag();**

Hope this helps.