# var that = this - can you please help me understand

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does var that = this; mean in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript)

I often find this assignment in Javascript code:

```
var that = this;
```

This is an example:

```
function Shape(x, y) {
    var that= this;

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.toString= function() {
        return 'Shape at ' + that.x + ', ' + that.y;
    };
}
```

Can you please explain why that is needed?

Please bear in mind I am very familiar with PHP or Java but not with the Javascript object model.

Comment: Wasn't there another question on this subject just a couple hours ago?

Comment: OFF: please remove "thanks, dan" from your question. A question is not meant to concern only one person, but the community.

Comment: @idiqual: `Dan` is the OP's name. He is not thanking `Dan`.

Comment: [Please Don't Use Signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Comment: Learn more about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: In this particular case, `that=this` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value is `this` is set when a function is called.

Setting `that` to `this` preserves that value for a function defined inside that function (since it would otherwise get a value for `this` that would depend on how *it* (the inner function) was called.

Answer (score 4):

It gives the inner function access to the instance that the Shape() method was called on. This type of variable access is called "closure." See here for more detail: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in the constructor function refers to the object that will be built from it. However, the `this` inside it's methods may not refer to that same object anymore.

So we work around that issue by preserving the `this` into the variable `that`. That way, we can still refer to the object created without using the `this` variable.

```
function Shape(x, y) {
    var that= this;

    this.toString= function() {
        //"this" in here is not the same as "this" out there
        //therefore to use the "this" out there, we preserve it in a variable
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Shape is a JavaScript class.  It has members toString() and private properties this.x
- this refers to the current class instance.
- In order for toString() to realize that it's operating under the 'current class instance', you assign that = this.  Since the variable 'that' can be accessed within the scope of toString().   Something this is called a 'me' operator.

Comment: Mmh. Strictly speaking there are no classes in JS. `Shape` is a constructor function. And private properties don't exist either, all properties are publicly accessible by any code that has a reference to the object.