# Reference error when calling a method inside a listener function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

```
function LolClass(){

    this.init = function(){             
        button_a.bind("tap", function(){                
            this.refreshFields(); // doesn't work 
            //refreshFields(); // doesn't work either
        });     
    }

    this.refreshFields = function(){
        alert("LOL");
    }

    this.dummy = function(){
        this.refreshFields(); // W O R K S!
    }
}
```

When I tap the button_a, I get a reference error, as refreshFields method isn't "found".

> Uncaught ReferenceError: refreshFields is not defined at
>   file:///android_asset/www/src/pages/main.js:70

But if I call that method in other places than that tap listener, it works.

I'm totally certain that the `this` inside the tap listener function is referencing to button_a, the event target.

My question is: What is the best(oo) fix for that?

Comment: I think `this` is referring to `button_a`, so it's not in the right scope. I'm not entirely sure but you might have to pass the parent object into the function to reference it inside.

Comment: What is `.bind()`? Is it part of some library? If so, does that `.bind()` method accept a `context` argument?

Comment: Note that this pattern in javascript is deprecated. If you forget the `new` operator, very bad things can happen. you should use `closure`.

Comment: @gdoron, can you provide me links related to that deprecation?

Comment: @MarceloAssis. A book - [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742)

Comment: Just to be sure, @amnotiam. my comment above is right, right...?

Comment: @amnotiam, it's from JQuery. It's just another way of adding an event listener.

Comment: @gdoron: If you mean the creation of objects via `new`, then I've got to disagree with you on that one. But then I disagree with lots of Crockford stuff.

Comment: @MarceloAssis: Alright, yeah jQuery's `.bind()` doesn't offer any way to override the calling context. It does however let you pass event data, which you could use instead of the `self` variable.

Comment: @amnotiam. Don't you think a missing `new` is risky? Why won't you use `closures`? I'm feel safe with Crockford behind me... :)

Comment: @gdoron: By closures, do you mean "functional inheritance", or something else? Either way, I think any misuse of an API is risky. The solution is usually to use the API properly. I will say that a nice pattern is to make a function that calls the constructor with `new` on your behalf, much like jQuery does. I've heard lots of Crockford advice that I entirely disagree with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
function LolClass(){

    var someVar = 0; 
    var self = this;

    this.init = function(){             
        button_a.bind("tap", function(){                
            self.refreshFields(); // now works!
            //refreshFields(); // doesn't work
        });     
    }

    this.refreshFields = function(){
        alert("LOL");
    }

    this.dummy = function(){
        this.refreshFields(); // W O R K S!
    }
}
```

Comment: When you copy his code and fix it, You can remove the "doesn't work"... `:)`

Comment: As all answers are correct, I'll accept the first submited. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should cache `this`:

```
var that = this; // "that" is a convention name for "this"
this.init = function(){             
        button_a.bind("tap", function(){                
            that.refreshFields(); 
        });     
    }
```

Comment: I didn't know that convention. Where can I find more about it?

Comment: @MarceloAssis. There is too much to know, it's just a name for the cached `this`. [Here is one question about it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4886632/601179)

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify your code:

```
function LolClass(){

    var someVar = 0; 
    var $this = this;

    this.init = function(){             
        button_a.bind("tap", function(){                
            $this.refreshFields();
        });     
    }

    this.refreshFields = function(){
        alert("LOL");
    }

    this.dummy = function(){
        this.refreshFields(); // W O R K S!
    }
}
```

"this" inside callback refers to different object. I added var $this = this; and used $this inside callback.

Comment: When you copy his code and fix it, You can remove the "doesn't work"... `:)`

Comment: `$this` is a bad name for `this` `$this` usually means `$(this)`. change it to `that` or `self`.