# Javascript OOP - lost this in asynchronous callback

Tags: javascript, oop, callback, this, prototype

I have problem which still bothers me on js oop - I'm sure I'm doing it bad, but I cant get how to do it right.

For example, I have this code

```
Auth.prototype.auth = function () {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', this.getAuthServerURL() + '/token', true);
    request.send();

    request.onloadend = function () {
      var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

      console.log(response);
      if(response.result == 'found') {
        var token = response.token;

        this.setToken(token);
        this.isSigned = true;
      } else {
        console.log('Not logged yet.');
      }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cant access to function setToken from context of "request.onloadend" function - its probably because I lost reference to "this".

Whats a solution of this problem? Can I somehow pass the "this" var to context of this function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The most direct is to simply save a copy of the value you need:

```
Auth.prototype.auth = function () {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var self = this; // save "this" value

    request.open('GET', this.getAuthServerURL() + '/token', true);
    request.send();

    request.onloadend = function () {
      var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

      console.log(response);
      if(response.result == 'found') {
        var token = response.token;

        self.setToken(token); // use saved "this" value
        self.isSigned = true;
      } else {
        console.log('Not logged yet.');
      }
    }
}
```

Another way is to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
request.onloadend = (function () {
  var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

  console.log(response);
  if(response.result == 'found') {
    var token = response.token;

    this.setToken(token); // use saved "this" value
    this.isSigned = true;
  } else {
    console.log('Not logged yet.');
  }
}).bind(this);
```

The second approach is "cleaner", but it has browser compatibility issues (IE < 9 does not support it).

Comment: I think the other is more direct, the code is minimally changed and you don't need to decide which pseudo keyword to use. Just saying.

Comment: @Esailija: Me too, but sadly its practical value is constrained by browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

[`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function:

```
Auth.prototype.auth = function () {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', this.getAuthServerURL() + '/token', true);
    request.send();

    request.onloadend = function () {
      var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

      console.log(response);
      if(response.result == 'found') {
        var token = response.token;

        this.setToken(token);
        this.isSigned = true;
      } else {
        console.log('Not logged yet.');
      }
    }.bind(this); //<-- bound
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just capture a reference to it in the outer scope, I've used the identifier `self`, however please feel free to give the name a more semantic meaning:

```
var self = this;
request.onloadend = function () {
  ...
  self.setToken(token);
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Capture `this` before the callback:

```
Auth.prototype.auth = function () {
    var self = this;

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', this.getAuthServerURL() + '/token', true);
    request.send();

    request.onloadend = function () {
      var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

      console.log(response);
      if(response.result == 'found') {
        var token = response.token;

        self.setToken(token);
        self.isSigned = true;
      } else {
        console.log('Not logged yet.');
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save `this` in a local var outside the callback.

```
Auth.prototype.auth = function () {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var _this = this;

    request.open('GET', this.getAuthServerURL() + '/token', true);
    request.send();

    request.onloadend = function () {
      var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

      console.log(response);
      if(response.result == 'found') {
        var token = response.token;

        _this.setToken(token);
        _this.isSigned = true;
      } else {
        console.log('Not logged yet.');
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are quite right: the callback is called with the `XMLHTTPRequest` object as the context (i.e. the value of `this`).  You need to give your instance another name, so that you can access it within the scope of the callback:

```
Auth.prototype.auth = function () {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        authInstance = this;

    request.open('GET', this.getAuthServerURL() + '/token', true);
    request.send();

    request.onloadend = function () {
      var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

      console.log(response);
      if(response.result == 'found') {
        var token = response.token;

        authInstance.setToken(token);
        authInstance.isSigned = true;
      } else {
        console.log('Not logged yet.');
      }
    }
}
```

[See this answer to another question for more explanation of why this is necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript/4886696#4886696). I have used `authInstance` rather than `self`, because I think it's generally good to use descriptive variable names; you'll never have to work out what `authInstance` means, whereas `self` might be ambiguous when someone in the future (possibly you!) reads the code.

Another option is to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), but that is probably more complicated than necessary here.

Comment: Modifying most of the code and using 2 separate "keywords" as well as an extra variable is less complicated than simply throwing `.bind(this)` at the end?

Comment: @Esailija I think the `bind` form is less intuitive and legible. The context only becomes clear at the end of the function, and the function is quite long. If it were a two-line function, I'd agree with you.

Comment: Inside a class `this` referring to the current instance of the class  ([no matter how the binding is implemented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch)), is more intuitive in my opinion. But we can disagree on that.