# Prototype Pattern and "this"

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, this, prototype-pattern

I'm trying to create a client-side api for a web control using the Prototype pattern. However I want to make life easier by not having to manage "this".

This is some sample code (i have commented the problematic line):

```
MyObject = function ()
{
    MyObject.initializeBase(this);

    this._someProperty = null;
};    

MyObject.prototype = {

    initialize: function()
    {
        // Init
    },

    get_someProperty: function()
    {
        return this._someProperty;
    },

    set_someProperty: function(value)
    {
        this._someProperty = value;
    },    

    doSomething: function ()
    {
        $('.some-class').each(function ()
        {
            $(this).click(this.doClick);  // this.doClick is wrong
        });
    },

    doClick: function ()
    {
        alert('Hello World');
    }
};
```

Normally, using the revealing module pattern I would declare a private variable:

```
var that = this;
```

Can I do something similar with the Prototype pattern?

Comment: So **what** is the problem again?

Comment: I want to avoid littering my code with managing "this" scope.

Comment: @Poz Sadly, you are programming in the wrong language if you want to avoid managing `this`.

Comment: I don't really get your problem. What do you expect? How would ECMAscript know which object you mean by referencing `this` twice within the same scope ?

Comment: @AlexWayne is this convention uncommon/bad? I tend to do it a lot in the revealing module/prototype patterns...

http://tinyurl.com/7dxkw

Comment: @jAndy see this question for what I'm hoping to achieve, but local to my prototype object [What does var that = this; mean in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the exact same thing you are used to, just do it within the `doSomething` method:

```
doSomething: function ()
{
    var instance = this;
    $('.some-class').each(function ()
    {
        $(this).click(instance.doClick);
    });
},
```

This approach has nothing to with `prototype` or not, it's just how to manage context with nested functions.  So when a function on a prototype (method) has nested functions within in, you may have to preserve the context `this` at any of those level if you want to access it in a nested scope.

Comment: I think the point was that he didn't want to do what you posted.  He wanted a "that" that is accessible in all methods and points to the correct this.

Comment: Well that's just how you do this javascript.  `this` needs to be managed when nested function scope is involved.  Not a way around it.  Unless you want to jumped into coffee script's fat arrow `=>` but I try not evangelize coffee script in every JS post :p

Comment: Thanks Alex, I could live with this solution. However as Matt points out it would be great if I had a single reference of "this" to point to.

Comment: Then use CoffeeScript and let the compiler deal with it :) http://tinyurl.com/9392ab5

Comment: If you are attaching methods to your prototype I think this is the only solution.  You could define the methods in your constructor but that actually wastes a lot of memory: https://gist.github.com/3073687

Comment: @Poz It may be good to add here that jQuery isn't helping overriding `this` in the each method, and relying on `(index, element)` arguments that it passes in may clean things up.

Answer (score 0):

ES5's `Function.prototype.bind()` might be an option for you. You could go like

```
doSomething: function ()
{
    $('.some-class').each(function(_, node)
    {
        $(node).click(this.doClick);  // this.doClick is right
    }.bind(this));
},
```

Now, we *proxied* each event handler by invoking `.bind()` and as a result, we call it in the context of the prototype object. The caveat here is, you no longer have `this` referencing the actuall *DOM node*, so we need to use the passed in arguments from jQuery instead.