# Variable reset when entering forEach (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I'm having a problem with my piece of code as the "this.items" variable turns to undefined when entering the following forEach.
As you can see there are to console.log that show that the this.items if redefined in the forEach

Why?

FYI, I'm using jQuery 1.8 and Classy (class manager for jQuery)

```
extractParams : function(params){

    if(params != ""){
        this.items = {};
        params = params.split("&");
        console.log(this.items);

        params.forEach( function(dts){
        console.log(this.items); // = undefined         
            this.keyval = dts.split("=");
            console.log(this.items);

            switch(keyval[0]){
                case "v" : 
                    this.items["Version number"] = this.keyval[1];
                    params = params.filter(function(v) { return !(v === "v=" + this.keyval[1] );});
                    break;
                case "t1" :
                    console.log(this.item);
                    this.items["Event Type"] = this.keyval[1];
                    params = params.filter(function(v) { return !(v === "t1=" + this.keyval[1] );});
                    break;
                default :
                case "" :
                    break;
            }

            switch(true){
                case regItem.test(keyval[0]):
                    this.items["Product Id n°" + this.keyval[0].match(regexpParamNumber)[1]] = this.keyval[1];
                    params = params.filter(function(v) { return !(v === "i"+this.keyval[0].match(regexpParamNumber)+"=" + this.keyval[1] );});
                    break;
                case regQuantity.test(keyval[0]):
                    this.items["Quantity n°" + keyval[0].match(regexpParamNumber)[1]] = keyval[1];
                    params = params.filter(function(v) { return !(v === "q"+keyval[0].match(regexpParamNumber)+"=" + keyval[1] );});
                    break;
                default :
                case "" :
                    break;
            }

        })
        console.log(result);
        result[0] = detectTrackerType(this.items);  
        show(result);
    }
    return this.items;
}
```

Comment: I think `this` is not what you expect anymore. Try to just `Console.log(this)` to see the object. Outside the `foreach` `this` is within the scope of the `extractParams` function but ones you in the `foreach` your `this` would be the local current object I believe.

Comment: try to output `this` after first and second use. i'd say they are pointing to different objects in those two cases

Answer (score 1):

It is the nature of 'this' -- every time you enter a function `this` gets reset.

Try

```
extractParams : function(params){
var that = this;
```

then use `that` throughout your code.

Edit: Found a discussion that is worth reading:
[What does 'var that = this;' mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: One of the weirdest answer I expected ... but it works ! Thank you :)

Comment: Yea, it is one of the less obvious warts about the language, I'll admit.  Editing my answer to include a link to a discussion.

Comment: @FrançoisPérez: `this` is context sensitive. If you are within a click event for example `this` is within the context of the event and would refer to the object that has been clicked on but if you add a `foreach` loop within the same event iterating through a list of items, `this` inside the `foreach` is now within the context of that loop and will refer to the current item being processed.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a little tricky in javascript. Try this doing `var self = this;` at the beggining of your function and then use `self` instead in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `this` to something else like `self` and then in your code refer to `self` instead of `this`

```
extractParams : function(params){
    var self = this;

    if(params != ""){
        self.items = {};
    ....
    params.forEach( function(dts){
        console.log(self.items); // = undefined
```

You need to do this because of the scope of `this` changes depending on where you are in the code. Within a nested function `this` is scoped to the inner function rather than the outer function.