# Why is aliasing 'this' in JS so bug prone?

Tags: javascript

Reading [Principles of writing consistent, idiomatic JavaScript](https://github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js/) in the section titled "Faces of `this`" it suggests that aliasing `this` in JavaScript is "extremely bug prone".

I personally try to use `_.bind()` (or something similar) whenever possible but does anyone know why aliasing `this` is so error prone?

Comment: This behavior is by design. (pun intended)

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you mean with "extremely bug prone"?  I have never heard about it... can you give some examples?

Comment: Thanks SLaks - I might be wrong, but I don't see that as 'aliasing'?  Or is it?  I think of 'aliasing' more in terms of `var that = this;`, which doesn't really cause any problems... But maybe I am just misunderstanding the question. :)

Comment: @Steve I was quoting "Principles of writing consistent, idiomatic JavaScript" where it suggests you not alias this (`var that = this;`) but instead use something like Underscore's `_.bind()`.

Comment: Oh, sorry Darrell, I just realized that we are wondering about the same question. I just looked up the link you provided and read their statement: "As a last resort, create an alias to this using self as an Identifier. This is extremely bug prone and should be avoided whenever possible."  --- I guess I am having the same question as you do: Why do they claim aliasing is error prone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are four meanings `this` can take dependending on how it was invoked.  Accordingly care must be taken to keep track of which `this` is being used, and I can think of `this`-prone problems in at least 3/4 of them.

### Invoked as method

In `obj.myFunc()`, `this` binds to `obj`.

This one can be scary if `myFunc` is passed in a callback, as it will forget that it was once part of an object and be invoked standalone. See e.g. [What does 'var that = this;' mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript) for the usual workaround to this.

### Invoked as standalone function

In plain `myFunc()`, `this` binds to global object.

### Invoked as constructor

Invoked as `new myFunc()` (very different! All functions that are intended to be invoked with `new` should be capitalized, thereby looking like a pseudoclass).  Creates a new object, binds it to `this` and (probably) returns that object.

Of course if you drop the `new` you will bind to the global object, which will likely clobber a lot of stuff and leave your program in a very broken state.  The capitalization convention is *very* important, and lets this problem be picked up by JSLint (IIRC).

### Invoked with apply (or call)

Invoked as `myFunc.apply(obj, args)`, in which `this` binds to `obj`.  Note this has security implications even, as any caller can swap out `this` with its own spoofed object.

Answer (score 4):

`this` being aliases everywhere would be bug prone because it gets rather difficult (for the developer) to remember exactly what `this` is referring to in a given situation. This can easily lead to a developer using `this` believing it refers to one element, when in reality it is something totally different. For example:

```
$('#something').click ( function (e) {
    //this refers to the clicked element
    var _this = this;  //Tracking a reference to the clicked element `this`
    $.each(someArray, function(index, value) {
       //this refers to the current element being iterated in someArray
       $.ajax({
          url : 'some/path',
          success: function (res) {
             //this refers to the ajax request
             //_this still references the clicked element
          } 
       })
    })
})
```

Furthermore, if you need to access one `this` from within the scope of another `this` (for instance this clicked element from within the ajax call) you have to keep a reference to it somehow. I have marked this in the code.

Comment: I'm rather partial to `var that = this;`.