# Usage of this keyword on chain method - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have an array of `DataTable` objects:

```
var scheme_tables = {
    length: 3,
    remittance-penalty-scheme: DataTable.Api._Api[0],
    reporting-penalty-scheme: DataTable.Api._Api[0],
    service-fee-scheme: DataTable.Api._Api[0],
    __proto__: Array[0]
}
```

I'm performing a callback to every `ajax` reload to each of these tables:

```
for(key in scheme_tables) {             
    scheme_tables[key].ajax.reload(reloader)
                                   ^^^^^^^^
}
```

And inside that `reloader` function, I have a `this` keyword:

```
var reloader = function() {
    console.log(this)
                ^^^^
}
```

Would the `this` keyword in the `reloader()` function refer to the `.ajax` property or the `scheme_tables[key]` object? Because when I perform `console.log(this)`, I receive a `Window` object-- should it be referring to the `DataTable` instance instead?

Comment: Your own test answers your question: `this` will be `window`.

Comment: @gillesc no, that's irrelevant.  What matters is how the function is invoked, not what object "owns" the function.

Comment: `this` is basically just an extra argument in JS, at least in the context of callbacks, you can set it to whatever you want

Comment: @dfsq Thats why I want to know the reason behind... because I'm expecting it to be attached to the `DataTable` instance and hence when I use `this` it should represent the `object` where it has been attached.

Comment: @Gideon in which case you need to use `.call(ctx, ...)` to invoke the callback within the `.reload` function, passing the required `this` value to `reloader`.

Comment: Then you should have asked question "why" and not "what will this be". And the answer to "why"-question is because in data tables they invoke callback as `callback( api.ajax.json() );` in which case context will be global object. So you expect `this` to be whatever, but developers decided to call callback in global context. If you really need it you can bind you callback to proper instance object.

Comment: For the various ways that `this` is controlled in Javascript, see this answer:  [What is a best practice for ensuring “this” context in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226751/what-is-a-best-practice-for-ensuring-this-context-in-javascript/16227099#16227099).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.bind` to create a reference to the `reloader` function that's bound to the required context:

```
for (key in scheme_tables) {
    var t = scheme_tables[key];                    
    t.ajax.reload(reloader.bind(t));
}
```

There's no need for the `hasOwnProperty` test - if anyone was messing with your `Object.prototype` then jQuery would be failing.  The jQuery devs have made a very deliberate decision *not* to use `hasOwnProperty` in jQuery's iteration functions.

Comment: Is there a big difference/advantage between using ``reloader.bind(t)`` and just passing the object as argument ``reloader(object)`` and using the ``object`` variable inside the function?

Comment: @gideon you can't just do `.reload(reloader(object))` because that will invoke `reloader` immediately with the supplied parameter instead of passing it as a callback.

Answer (score 0):

In javascrpt keyword `this` inside a function is bound to whatever is left of the dot at the time of invocation. In your code reload internally invokes reloader function. And since it calls it without dont notation, `this` would be attached to window.

It doesnt matter where and how function is defined, this word always is defined at execution.

Or you can manaually specify what this would refer to using `.bind`

I would urge you to lookup udacity object oriented javascript course.

Comment: you can't be _sure_ that `this === window` without looking at the actual invocation.  If it uses `.call` or `.apply` then it could be set to anything.