# why invoke an inner function instead of a method?

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I understand that JavaScript automatically assigns each function/method the parameter `this`, and that `this` is bound to the object which contains it.

A method is a function stored as the property of an object. So in a method, `this` can be used to modify or retreive values from the object that contains it. But if that method is invoked as a function, not as the property of an object, then `this` is bound to global, not to the object.

The workaround is to assign:

```
var that = this;
```

inside the method, so that an inner function can have access to `this` through the variable `that`.

My question is: Why is this workaround necessary? Can't you just use methods all the time? Why would you invoke a perfectly good method as an inner function, and then have to make another variable so that it has the access it would have had had it been invoked as a method instead?

I must be missing something important here, if there were a dumb-question tag, I would use it.  (can someone make one?)

Comment: This answer has a lot of good info around closures: http://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/573218

Comment: Note that ECMAScript introduces [arrow functions](http://robcee.net/2013/fat-arrow-functions-in-javascript) which preserve this. By using them, you could effectively get away without the horrible `_this = that = self = this` nonsense. As a side-note, I think `this` is terrible because of its ambiguous name, and using a synonym such as `that` does very little do help. Using something descriptive that actually clearly indicates the object being referred to does wonders for understanding code like this (hahaha).

Comment: @Barney nice, the => function looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that I understand your question right . because the way you put it is a bit of mind-f*** XD .

but from what i understood . im going to answer your question as in "what do we use the `that` trick for ? ".

So here is a perfectly healthy object .

```
var myobject = {
    firstMethod : function(){
        this.secoundMethod(); // calls the other method

    },
    scoundMethod : function(){
        return 'hi from method 2' ;
    }
}
```

and now i want to do some jquery magic (or any other thing that has a call back function) .
im going to use jQuery but feel free to do other things .

```
var myobject = {
    firstMethod : function(){
        var _this = this ;
        this.secoundMethod(); // calls the other method

        $('.myClass').animate({'width':300} , 300 , function(){
            // this is a call back functon which will be called as soon as the animation ends
            // the problem is that if i call @var : `this` , it wont work because im in 
            // another scope other than the firstMethod .
            // so the following will throw an error .
            this.secoundMethod(); // error

            // to solve this you need the @var : `that` , or in my case i love it to be _this
            _this.scoundMethod() // this will work .


        })

    },
    scoundMethod : function(){
        return 'hi from method 2' ;
    }
}
```

So mainly `_this` (in my case) is used to scope things . so I can access the object scope inside other scope .
to be honest i have used this trick in other places (in like 99% of cases);

even the 1% that is left is basically the same idea but with much deeper nesting or with lots of closures and stuff like that.

### How dangerous can this be ?!

Well it depends on how smart you are . here is another brain example

```
var myobject = {
    firstMethod : function(){
        var _this = this ,
            someObject : {

                firstMethod  : function(){
                    this.scoundMethod(); // if you log this you will get 'the wrong method'.
                    _this.scoundMethod(); // in here you get 'hi from method 2'.

                },
                scoundMethod : function(){
                    return 'the wrong method';
                }
            };

    },
    scoundMethod : function(){
        return 'hi from method 2' ;
    }
}
```

As you can see this is dangerous not because it doesn't work , but the fear id that it works . because if you have similarly named functions and you have a missed-up scope you end up with hours and hours of digging . While if you dont have that .. you will get just a nice error which you can fix right away

### How long can this go .

will you can nest as much as you like . but there are consequences (rarely huh?!).
enjoy the following and dont ever attempt that at home .

```
var myobject = {
    firstMethod : function(){
        var _this = this ,
            someVar = [1 , 2 , 3 ] ;

            this.scoundMethod(function(){
                var that = this;
                $.each(someVar,function(elementName){
                    var them = this;
                    $('.'+elementName).animate({} , 300 , function(){
                        console.log(them) // logs the element
                        console.log(_this.scoundMethod()) // logs 'hi from method 2'
                    })
                })
            }

    },
    scoundMethod : function(){
        return 'hi from method 2' ;
    }
}
```

### Other resources :

- [Scope and this in JavaScript](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/)  - *by Jack Franklin*
- [“this” and “that”: understanding execution context in javascript](http://stevenmhunt.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/this-and-that-understanding-execution-context-in-javascript/) - *by stevenmhunt*

Hope I have made it simple . And that I didn't answer the wrong question .

Comment: your second example is very illuminating. It shows that a method's `this` only binds to the same depth as the method, so to bind to a higher depth, `that` variable is needed. like rockerest posted, the alternative would be to reaccomplish the scope for each nested method.

Comment: yeah i have made that clear in the `How long can this go .` section . it even feels weird when i say this and that .. scope is just like inception  dont go deep or you will be lost for ever , hoo (then he fades slowly )

Answer (score 2):

The question of `this` and `that` has been eloquently and succinctly answered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4886696/597122), so I'll answer your question: why invoke an inner function?

## Why not?

Using the linked answer as a jumping off point:

```
$('#element').click(function(){
    // this is a reference to the element clicked on

    var that = this;

    $('.elements').each(function(){
        // this is a reference to the current element in the loop
        // that is still a reference to the element clicked on
    });
});
```

What would the benefit be of instantiating a new object, passing in all the variables you need, and manually constructing the proper environment *just to loop over some elements*? You have the proper environment right here, and the scope is exactly where you need it.

If you need access to the `this` variable within an inner scope, you'll need to re-assign it, since it's being re-purposed in the inner scope.
In this case, some people use `that` which isn't very illuminating in my opinion, but it's just a way of passing scope to these highly useful *temporary inner scopes*.

And that's really the key, it's *temporary* scope changing. There's no reason to create an entirely new scope, symbol tables, etc, etc, when you've got it all right here.

Comment: So a method invoked from within a method loses scope?  It's not just when you call it as a function?  I thought there was a difference there... This directly answers the question:  you would have to reproduce the scope for each nested method.  Is that right?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand the second part of your comment, but as to the first part - "a method invoked from within a method loses scope" - I can say: it definitely doesn't! That's one of the great things about JavaScript's function-level scope definitions instead of block-level. When you enter an inner function, it still has access to it's parent scope; @Hussein demonstrates this above. What I'm demonstrating is that when you enter the inner function, the `this` variable is usually changed by entering it's scope, so you need to provide access to the originating `this` for it.

Answer (score 2):

Execution context changes for callbacks in events and timers. So the value of this becomes window.

Assigning this to that(or self)  'that' becomes a variable that can accessed through closure. The 'that' gives 'this' to the callback.

Some stuff to google: javascript closure, execution context, javascript self, javascript timer/event context.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons is that you may want to `call` or `apply` that method on any other object if you set as its context.

```
    var obj = {
        name: 'foo'
    },

    logger = function (name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.log = function () {
            console.log(this.name)
        }
    };

    var bar = new logger('bar');
    bar.log(); // -> 'bar'
    bar.log.call(obj); // -> 'foo'
```