# How can I use a class method as onclick handler in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, javascript-objects

Consider the following Javascript class:

```
function ClassA() {
 this.someVariable = someValue;
 this.myHandler = function(){
   // I WANT TO CALL InnerFunction
   this.innerFunction();
 };

 this.innerFunction = function(){
   // do something that accesses/manipulates someVariable
 };

 this.hookUp = function(id){
   document.getElementById(id).onclick = this.myHandler;
 };
};
...
...
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.setAttribute('id','mybuttonid');
// append button to the document
...
...
var x = new ClassA();
x.hookUp('mybuttonid');
```

When I click on the button, the handler executes, however, 'this' now refers to the button element instead of the ClassA object, so it cannot resolve innerFunction().

What i need to have is a way to indicate to the handler that the context of this is the instance of ClassA (similar to $.ajax({context: this....})  where you can use 'this' in the .done() or .error() handlers), or a way to pass a reference to the instance to the handler without making the handler execute at instantiation time.  For example if I try to pass 'this' as a praremter to myHandler (myHandler=function(ref){}, and then change : document.getElementById(id).onclick = this.myHandler(this);)
But as you add parameters to myHandler, the function is executed at class instantiation time instead of at click time.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `this.someVariable` try just using `var someVariable`. `someVariable` will only be available within the scope of the function, so shouldn't be any need for `this`. Also there's no such thing as classes in JavaScript, so your idea of using `this` might be misguided.

Comment: Thanks.. perhaps I was not very clear, my main problem is accessing innerFunction().  I am trying to write code that resembles OO so it would be easier to understand and maintain, at least for me :) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace...

```
this.myHandler = function(){
    this.innerFunction();
};
```

... with ...

```
var self = this;
this.myHandler = function() {   
    self.innerFunction();
};
```

See [this article by Crockford](https://crockford.com/javascript/private.html). Cite:

> By convention, we make a private `that` variable. This is used to make
>   the object available to the private methods. This is a workaround for
>   an error in the ECMAScript Language Specification which causes `this` to
>   be set incorrectly for inner functions.

See also [What does 'var that = this;' mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: You, sir, have saved me hours of digging for solutions. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Like you already discovered, the value of `this` depends on how the method is called.  Thus, it can be confusing when using `this` within event handlers attached to DOM elements.

Instead, when adding handlers, use an an anonymous method along with a variable within a closure.

For example, change your hookup function to be:

```
this.hookUp = function(id) {
    var _this = this;
    document.getElementById(id).onclick = function() {
      _this.innerFunction();
    }
}
```

Notice that you no longer depend on `thi`s from within the onclick handler and thus avoid the problem.  Once you're in `innerFunction`, you can continue to use `this` as you normally would, as it now correctly points to the correct object.

For a deeper explanation on how `this` works in functions, MDN has a nice [article about the `this` keyword.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Thanks, useful and well explained.

Answer (score -1):

this is a commonly solved using what's called 'Proxy Pattern'.

I think this will help (-!

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#proxypatternjquery