# How can I access properties of object from a function that's within its methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning OOP javascript... In my example code, I can't access properties and methods from within the ajax methods ... why, and what would be the right way to do that?
http://jsbin.com/votajaxo/1/

```
var Person = function(name){
    this.name = name;
};

Person.prototype = {
    doAjax: doAjax,
    changeName: changeName
};

function doAjax(url){
    console.log(this.name); // John

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            console.log(this.name); // undefined
            console.log(typeof this.changeName); // undefined
            xhr.abort();
        }
    });
}

function changeName(newName){
    this.name = newName;
}

var p = new Person('John');
p.doAjax('/handler');
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript. There are many dups. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use a closure to retain reference to the "this" of the object:

```
var Person = function(name){
    this.name = name;
};

Person.prototype = {
    doAjax: doAjax,
    changeName: changeName
};

function doAjax(url){
    var context = this;
    console.log(this.name); // John

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            console.log(context.name); // John
            console.log(typeof context.changeName); 
            xhr.abort();
        }
    });
}

function changeName(newName){
    this.name = newName;
}

var p = new Person('John');
p.doAjax('/handler');
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitly set the context in which your closure will be called; jQuery provides this functionality via the `context:` option to `$.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    context: this, // <-- add this
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        console.log(this.name);
        console.log(typeof this.changeName);
        xhr.abort();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also `bind` your desired context to callback.. so that when it gets executed it gets proper context.

```
function doAjax(url){
    console.log(this.name); // John

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            console.log(this.name); // undefined
            console.log(typeof this.changeName); // undefined
            xhr.abort();
        }.bind(this) // <-- binds call to current context.
    });
}
```

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/23/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/