# JS scope/reference issue

Tags: javascript

I have a JS module:

```
var myModule = {

   f1 : function(){...},

   f2 : function(){...},

   f3 : function(){

   // this works
   this.f2();

   var objRef = this;

   chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(){

          // this works
          objRef.f2();

          // this doesn't work
          this.f2();

   }
```

When, from the body of the listener block inside f3 I call f2 using this, I can't call it, probably because of a scope issue.

Question: is there any way to avoid the objRef solution to reference f2 function from the body of the listener?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does var that = this; mean in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: @delnan I don't think so. The question and its answers you referenced discuss the usage of `var that/self = this`. It seems that the OP in this question already knows about the concept, but tries to find a cleaner way.

Comment: @ComFreek OP doesn't seem to be aware of it. But yes, that other question doesn't address how to get rid of `objRef`. Retracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener((function(){

  // this works
  objRef.f2();

  // this will now work!
  this.f2();

}).bind(this));
```

Easier and cleaner approach (– if the call of `f2` is the only statement which shall be executed):

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener( this.f2.bind(this) );
```

Comment: Interesting: I was wondering how to pass this and I (poor me) tried to pass it as a function argument   :-)

Comment: @3000 Actually, you don't need any callback function. You can also use `chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(this.f2.bind(this));`