# $(this) not working on click when using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the glyphicons from twitter's bootstrap. When a user posts a status update, I want other users to be able to like, dislike or favorite that post. After they have liked the post, I want the color of the glyphicon to change so that they know they've pushed the button. From other stack overflow posts, I've found ways to do this without jQuery. But I want to use jQuery to accomplish it. Currently, when I use `$(this).toggleClass(tst)` to add the color I want, the color doesn't change. I know my ajax is working because database is updated based on the specific post that I clicked.

The strange thing is, if I use $("#liked").toggleClass(tst), the color does change, but only on the first post that uses the #liked id. I've tried using, toggleClass, addClass, removeClass/addClass .css and also calling the $(this).toggleClass(tst) inside and outside of the function. It all comes down to the same thing: When I use `this` it doesn't change colors. How can I (using jQuery) to target the specific liked button so that I can change its class.

```
echo "<a id='liked' href='#' <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up'></span> </a>";
```

Here is the css from twitter's bootstrap

```
.glyphicon-thumbs-up:before{
    content:"\e125"; 
    color: #7f8c8d; 
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.glyphicon-thumbs-up.tst:before{
    content:"\e125"; 
    color: green; 

}
```

here is my jQuery

```
$(".glyphicon").click(function() {

   var socialButton = $(this).attr('id');

   //traverse the dom up until I get to this post's text. Get the text from the post
        var thisPost = $(this).parent().parent().text();

   //get the user name of the post
   var user = $(this).parent().parent().parent().text();



    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "socialbuttons.php", 
    data: { 
          button: socialButton,
          post: thisPost,
          postAuthor: user
        },
        success: function(data) {
           $( this ).toggleClass("tst");
              alert("success")//this works
           //$("#liked").toggleClass("tst"); //works, but only on first post

        }
    })

    })
```

Comment: I see that your code generates invalid HTML, i.e. `<a id='liked' href='#' <span ...`

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: sir correct your HTML..It's nbot generating valid HTML A tag

Comment: @K.K.Agarwal what's wrong with the html? How I should I write it?

Comment: echo "<a id='liked' href='#'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up'></span> </a>";  ... you were missing >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to preserve that object because in ajax success `$(this)` refers to ajax only(not the current clicked element)

```
$(".glyphicon").click(function () {
    var socialButton = $(this).attr('id');
    //traverse the dom up until I get to this post's text. Get the text from the post
    var thisPost = $(this).parent().parent().text();
    //get the user name of the post
    var user = $(this).parent().parent().parent().text();
    var obj = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "socialbuttons.php",
        data: {
            button: socialButton,
            post: thisPost,
            postAuthor: user
        },
        success: function (data) {
            obj.toggleClass("tst");
            alert("success") //this works
                //$("#liked").toggleClass("tst"); //works, but only on first post

        }
    })

})
```

Answer (score 2):

In the success callback you're referencing the wrong `this`; you can fix it by passing it via `$.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    context: this, // <--- added
    url: "socialbuttons.php", 
    data: { 
        button: socialButton,
        post: thisPost,
        postAuthor: user
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $( this ).toggleClass("tst");
        alert("success")//this works
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong "this" in the success handler - it points to the global window object (or might point to some object related to the ajax request in this case, but anyway). Learn to use the "that = this" pattern from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript).

Also, you can write `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`.
Oh, and use `.closest()` instead of cascaded `.parent()`s. Or even better, `$('.dunno-the-classname').on('click', '.glyphicon', function () { ... });` - lookup the jQuery docs for the second parameter of  `.on()`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your click function:

```
var icon = $(this);
```

And instead of

```
$(this).toggleclass("tst");
```

use

```
icon.toggleClass("tst");`
```