# Getting TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined when trying to add to array

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, asp.net-web-api, typescript

I'm trying to learn typescript. In this attempt, I am trying to get an array of numbers, from a webservice I have created, into a javascript array.

I have the following Typescript class:

```
class GameMap2 {
    Grid: Uint8Array;
    width: number;
    height: number;

    constructor(height: number, width: number) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.Grid = new Uint8Array(height * width);
    }

    generateMap() {
        alert("calling generate");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Maps/" + this.width + "/" + this.height,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Ajax success");
                for (var idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
                    this.Grid[idx] = data[idx];
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

From the webservice, I will get something like:   `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`
Now, when I try to loop through this result, and put it into the Grid array, I get the error:
`TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

If I change it to `This.Grid.Push(data[idx]);` I get undefined errors.
It seems to me, that my Grid array is not actually within reach of my ajax callback. Can that really be true, or am I doing something wrong here?
Is there another way I can get my array into the javascript array?

Comment: `this` : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in fact, this issue is solved directly by TypeScript. The feature is called `arrow function` and would change your code defintion like this

```
class GameMap2 { 
    ...
    constructor(height: number, width: number) { ... }

    generateMap() {
        alert("calling generate");
        $.ajax({

            // instead of this
            // success: function(data) {
            // use this style, and the compiler will do the magic
            // of keeping correct "this" for us
            success: (data) => {
                alert("Ajax success");
                for (var idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
                    this.Grid[idx] = data[idx];
                }
            }
         ....
```

See [TypeScript Arrow Function Tutorial](http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/arrow-function-typescript-tutorial/) `(small cite)`

> ... “Arrow function expressions are a compact form of function expressions that omit the function keyword and have lexical scoping of this.” Basically the Arrow Function helps you retain a certain scope automatically. If you look at the outputted code from the compiler, it just creates a var _this = this; and it is used inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `this` has changed context in the success callback. Make a reference to `this` and use that instead:

```
generateMap() {
  alert("calling generate");
  var _this = this;
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/Maps/" + this.width + "/" + this.height,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Ajax success");
      for (var idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
        _this.Grid[idx] = data[idx];
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It's the `this` and `that` convention. The following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript shows why and how to use it.

Comment: I use `_this` because that's the code convention I've chosen.