# this fetch call issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have the following code inside a backbone view:

```
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function() {
    this.render();
},

render: function() {

  this.model.fetch({
    success : function(model, resp, opt) {
       alert(this.$el.html() ); //THIS ONE DOESN'T WORK?
    }
  });
  alert(this.$el.html() ); // THIS ONE WORKS FINE
}

});
```

I have two `alert(this.$el.html() );` calls, one outside the fetch, and one inside. But for some reason, the one outside the fetch call works, but the one inside the fetch call returns an error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `success`, `this` is no longer the `View` (it is `undefined` in strict mode, or `window` otherwise).

To fix this, you can use the common `var that = this` idiom; For more info on the idiom, see here: [What does 'var that = this;' mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript)

```
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function() {
    this.render();
},

render: function() {
  var that = this; // define here

  this.model.fetch({
    success : function(model, resp, opt) {
       alert(that.$el.html() ); // Use that instead of this here.
    }
  });
  alert(this.$el.html() ); // THIS ONE WORKS FINE
}

});
```

Alternate option: See .bind() - A decent recourse: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

```
render: function() {
  this.model.fetch({
    success : function(model, resp, opt) {
       alert(that.$el.html() ); 
    }.bind(this) // this.model.fetch.success now has bound 'this' permanently for any call to success from this method form here on out. 
  });
  alert(this.$el.html() );
}
```

Comment: Since this was accepted can you please add to your answer the reference to .bind AND remove the OP comments. Give any readers the opportunity to figure out which is best for their scenario.

Comment: @relic: on the road atm. I've CW'd my post, so feel free to make the changes yourself, or I'll do it soon!

Comment: Hey cool, nice on the road answer :+1:

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `this` inside a JavaScript function depends on how the function is called rather than how or where it is defined (except for bound functions of course). The [`Model#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) documentation doesn't specify any particular `this` for the `success` callback so it is probably being called as a plain function (i.e. `this` is `window` inside the `success` callback). The result is that `this.$el` is `undefined` inside your `success` callback.

You have various options:

1. Use the standard `var _this = this` trick to tunnel the desired context into the callback:

   ```
   var _this = this;
   this.model.fetch({
     success : function(model, resp, opt) {
       alert(_this.$el.html());
     }
   });
   ```
2. Use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to use a bound function as the callback:

   ```
   this.model.fetch({
     success : function(model, resp, opt) {
       alert(this.$el.html());
     }.bind(this)
   });
   ```
3. Use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) to bind the callback to the desired `this`:

   ```
   this.model.fetch({
     success : _(function(model, resp, opt) {
       alert(this.$el.html());
     }).bind(this)
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have access to 'this' anymore, the inside call to 'this' is referencing the callback function actually.

Try binding 'this' to the return function, or setting 'this' to a variable inside the render scope to 'self' or something.

1-

```
render: function() {
  this.model.fetch({
    success : function(model, resp, opt) {
       alert(this.$el.html() );
    }
  }.bind(this)); //Passes 'this' along for execution on the callback. 
  alert(this.$el.html() );
}
```

2-

```
render: function() {
  var self = this;
  this.model.fetch({
    success : function(model, resp, opt) {
       alert(self.$el.html() ); //the scope of 'self' makes it in here
    }
  };
  alert(this.$el.html() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in javascript is the current context. So for instance if `success()` would be called as click event handler from a button, then `this` would be the button.

Try to inspect what `this` in the `success()` method really is. Read a good tutorial about closures, e.g.: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml

As a quick solution, I recommend this correction:

```
render: function() {

  var that = this; // <<<<< Change 1

  this.model.fetch({
    success : function(model, resp, opt) {
      //alert(this.$el.html() ); //THIS ONE DOESN'T WORK?
      alert(that.$el.html() ); // <<<<<< Change 2
    }
   });
  alert(this.$el.html() ); // THIS ONE WORKS FINE
}
```

Should do the trick.