# Javascript instance variable showing as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have created a Javascript object that adds a click listener onto certain classes which then in turn calls a PHP function to generate results from a MYSQL/PHP driven backend. 
The backend is working fine (and the results are being returned correctly). I am having an issue where the instance thinks that a property (a string) of the instance is empty, even after I have directly assigned values to that property.

Here is my code:

```
//Workout Videos Class
var Workout = function(offset, limit, element, categoryId) {
    this.offset = offset;
    this.html = "";
    this.limit = limit;
    this.element = element;
    this.categoryId = categoryId
    var self = this;

    jQuery(this.element).on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        self.seeMoreClick(this, self.videoCallBack, self)
    });
}

Workout.prototype.seeMoreClick = function(item, videoCallBack, thisArg) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type      :   'POST',
        dataType  :   'json',
        url       :   'api/get-videos',
        data      :   'category_id=' + this.categoryId + "&offset=" + this.offset + "&limit=" + this.limit,
        success   : function(data) {
            videoCallBack.call(thisArg, data, item);
        }
    });
}

Workout.prototype.videoCallBack = function(response, item) {
    this.offset = response.offset;
    if(response.videos) {   
        jQuery(response.videos).each(function(key, video) {                     
            this.html += "<div class='col-md-4' data-related-video='" + video.videoId + "'>";
                this.html += '<a href="#" class="dashboard-video"></a>';
                this.html += '<div class="video-information">';
                    this.html += '<h5 class="tk-bebas-neue">' + video.videoName + '</h5>';
                    this.html += '<p>' + video.videoDesc + '</p>';
                    this.html += '<p>Equipment: ';
                    jQuery(video.equipment).each(function(equipKey, equipmentItem) {
                        this.html += '<a href="#" class="equipment-item" data-equipment-id="' + equipmentItem.equipmentId + '">' + equipmentItem.equipmentName + '</a>';
                    });
                    this.html += "</p>";
                    this.html += '<div class="video-rating" data-rel="' + video.videoId + '" data-user-id="' + video.userId + '">'; 


                    this.html += "</div>";
                this.html += '</div>';
            this.html += "</div>";              
        });
    } else {
        this.html += "<div class='col-md-12'>No more videos to show</div>";
    }
    console.log(this.html);
    jQuery("#" + jQuery(this.element).attr("data-related") + " .col-md-8").append(this.html);
}
```

The problem I am having is in the 'videoCallBack' function which I am using to pass to the AJAX function in order to ensure it resolves before all the code is run. The 'this.html' property is showing as empty when I log it in the console directly after setting it. Can anyone see why this may be happening?
Thanks

Comment: watch your uses of `this`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript "this" keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Comment: Ok, found a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

This is a result of `this` changing in your code.  Inside the forEach block '`this`' refers to a different object, so you're adding all that HTML to a completely different object.

A simple fix is to save off a reference to this:

```
Workout.prototype.videoCallBack = function(response, item) {
    var self = this;
    self.offset = response.offset;
    if(response.videos) {   
        jQuery(response.videos).each(function(key, video) {                     
            self.html += "<div class='col-md-4' data-related-video='" + video.videoId + "'>";
           ...
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have a function execution, you need to be mindful of the value of `this` since it'll change based on how the function is called. It's never automatically inherited from its enclosing environment.

So in your case, the callback you pass to `.each()` has a `this` value that's different from the outer environment. You'll need to bind the `this` value or store it in a varaible and reference the variable inside the callback.

To bind it, you can use `$.proxy()`.

```
 // -----------------------------v
jQuery(response.videos).each($.proxy(function(key, video) {   

    this.html += "<div class='col-md-4' data-related-video='" + video.videoId + "'>";
    // ...and so on...       

}, this));
//   ^
```

or the native `.bind()` method in modern browsers.

```
jQuery(response.videos).each(function(key, video) {   

    this.html += "<div class='col-md-4' data-related-video='" + video.videoId + "'>";
    // ...and so on...       

}.bind(this));
//  ^
```

Both of these will return a new function that has the `this` value permanently bound to the value you provided. This avoids having to add another variable to the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not accessing the right 'this'.
Within the scope of your each function another 'this' is present.
Avoid this by setting a variable

```
var self = this;
```

And use that instead to preserve your context.

```
this.html to self.html
```