# How to bind "this" in $http.post -> resolve / reject in AngularJS? (right now this = Window object)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, this

I'm writing a wrapper library that has a save function. Basically it just calls the `$http.post` function and returns the promise (for sake of brevity).

Unfortunately the `this` operator in the function that gets called when the promise is resolved (i.e. the function which gets called with the *result data*) points to the `Window` object. So I'm wondering if there is a way to bind the `this` operator to another object, when the promise is resolve or rejected?

Please look at the code below to help make more sense:

```js
angular.module('SomeService', []).service('$service', function($http) {
  this.get = function() {
    return $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com');
  }

  return this;
});

angular.module('testApp', ['SomeService']).controller('testController', function($service) {
  $service.get().then(function(data) {
    alert(this);
    //It should say Object Window!
    //Is is possible to bind `this` to say SomeService (example),
    //Or some other object?

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
  {{1+1}}
</div>
```

If you run the code above, the alert says [Object Window]. **So my question is:** Is possible to bind `this` to say SomeService (example), or some other object?

P.S. One idea is maybe I can write a wrapper for `$http.get` instead of returning the promise directly and then somehow bind the `this` operator before resolving my own promise? But I can't find any info on how to resolve promises with (`this`) binding.

**Update:** Thanks for the suggestions.. **I know about bind, but the case is a little more complicated.** the SomeService.save method creates an Item object. So the function that calls SomeService.save() needs both the item created and the data returned by the $http request when the promise is resolved. I figured out that I just set this to the new Item Object and pass the data from $http as-is. Does that make any sense? If not, please tell me and I'll create a plunkr trying to explain the same.

Comment: Use `.then(function() { }.bind(SomeService))`

Comment: Maybe this will help you: [what does var that = this mean in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

That's what [the `bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) is for.

```
then(function(data) { ... }.bind(window))
```

Comment: Or using fat arrow functions: `data => {}` which will inherit the context from it's parent scope.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the parent context isn't `window`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.. I know about `bind`, but the case is a little more complicated.. the `SomeService.save` method creates an `Item` object. So the function that calls `SomeService.save()` needs both the item created and the data returned by the $http request when the promise is resolved. I figured out that I just set `this` to the new `Item` Object and pass the `data` from $http as-is. Does that make any sense? If not, please tell me and I'll create a plunkr trying to explain the same.. Thanks.