# How to defined a new variable in AngularJS component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, progress-bar, components, angularjs-components

I have trying to create a AngularJS component corresponding to a progress bar. Here is a JSFiddle created for this question http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6725/

Here is my application and component definition:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
    $scope.total = 20;
    $scope.count = 15;

    $scope.changeTotal = function(value){$scope.total += value};
    $scope.changeCount = function(value){$scope.count += value};
});

myApp.component('progressBar', {
    bindings: {
        percentage: '=',
    },
    controller: function() {
        this.width = this.percentage * 100;
    },
    template: '<div class="progressBar">\
            <div class="inner" style="width: [[$ctrl.width]]%"></div>\
        </div>',
});
```

And the following HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    Total: {{total}}, <button ng-click="changeTotal(-1)">-</button><button ng-click="changeTotal(+1)">+</button><br/>
    Count: {{count}}, <button ng-click="changeCount(-1)">-</button><button ng-click="changeCount(+1)">+</button><br/>
    Percentage: {{count / total}}%<br/>
    <br/>

    <progress-bar percentage="{{count / total}}"></progress-bar>

  </div>
</div>
```

Despite the definition of the `width` attribute in the component controller, AngularJS can not find it in the template defined.

I have some difficulty to debug this code efficiently since I just started learning AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `=` (two way binding) in component, then you shouldn't be using `{{}}` in percentage attribute value. Direct calculated value can passed to `percentage` attribute wrapped with `()` parenthesis.

While binding percentage for showing progress bar, you could use `ng-style` directive with `$ctrl.percentage` value which has been passed to component `bindings`.

**HTML**

```
<progress-bar percentage="{{(count / total)}}"></progress-bar>
```

**Directive Tempalte**

```
template: '<div class="progressBar">\
        <div class="inner" ng-style="{ width: $ctrl.percentage+\'%\'}"></div>\
    </div>',
```

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/peuh9e4m/)

Comment: The component's width will never change because it only sets the percentage on render, the value could be attached to a common service to handle it dynamically correctly.

Comment: @Goliadkin dear sir, did you checked fiddle? this is how `=` is used for two way bidning,,

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks ! The progress bar does not move, so despite your modification, it is not working :( I have edited it to set up the width correctly  (a `*100` was missing) : http://jsfiddle.net/p8xqyhng/2/
Second question, was the var `self = this;` is used for ?

Comment: @fef Oh sorry I missed that part.. I used `var self = this;` to reduced [*`this vs that`*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript) problem in future..

Comment: @fef also look at the updated Fiddle.. yesterday I forgot to save fiddle before adding it to answer

Comment: @PankajParkar Works for me ! Thanks again ;)