# Function in function in class

Tags: javascript

I have a class named Terminal in which I have a function constructor in which i have an anonymous function in which I would like to get access to the output() function in Terminal class. How can I do this?

Using this.output() throws an error. (this.output is not a function)

```
class Terminal
{
    constructor(contentID, inputID, options)
    {
        if (!contentID || !inputID || !options)
        {
            return false;
        }
        this.cid = contentID;
        this.iid = inputID;
        if (!options['pcName'] || !options['username'])
        {
            return false;
        }
        this.pcname = (options['pcName'].replace('<', '&lt;')).replace('>', '&rt;');
        this.username = options['username'];
        this.version = '0.01';
        // commands
        this.commandsList = [];
        this.commandsList['whoami'] = function(){ Terminal.output('lol') };

        console.log('terminal.js version ' + this.version + ' initializing');
        this.output('ja', true);
        this.output('whoami', true);
        this.output('i dont know bro', false, 'whoami');
    }

    output (text, prefix, cmdName) // cmdName is matters only when prefix is false
    {
        if (this.cid && text)
        {
            if (prefix == true)
            {
                text = this.username + '@' + this.pcname + ':~$ ' + text;
            }
            else if (cmdName)
            {
                text = cmdName + ': ' + text;
            }
            var con = document.getElementById(this.cid);
            con.innerHTML = con.innerHTML + text + '<br>';
        }
    }

    makeCommand (cmd)
    {
        if (cmd && cmd != '' && this.commandsList)
        {
            cmd = (cmd.replace('<', '&lt;')).replace('>', '&rt;');
            if (this.commandsList[cmd])
            {
                console.log('Executing ' + cmd);
                this.commandsList[cmd]();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this.output(), output() and Terminal.output() - without result.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/95seeX7x It's chaotic but anonymous function which I mean is in line 21 and it is called in 54.

Comment: @Dante383 you have to post that with your question (I did it already for you), we're not wizards. Also, it would be helpful if you paste the error as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure it's the answer, I think you need to define a new variable: `that` equal to `this`. Then call the method like so: `that.Output()`

```js
class Terminal
{
    constructor(contentID, inputID, options)
    {
        if (!contentID || !inputID || !options)
        {
            return false;
        }
        this.cid = contentID;
        this.iid = inputID;
        if (!options['pcName'] || !options['username'])
        {
            return false;
        }
        this.pcname = (options['pcName'].replace('<', '&lt;')).replace('>', '&rt;');
        this.username = options['username'];
        this.version = '0.01';
        // commands
        this.commandsList = [];
        var that = this;
        this.commandsList['whoami'] = function(){ that.output('lol') };
 
        console.log('terminal.js version ' + this.version + ' initializing');
        this.output('ja', true);
        this.output('whoami', true);
        this.output('i dont know bro', false, 'whoami');
    }
   
    output (text, prefix, cmdName) // cmdName is matters only when prefix is false
    {
        if (this.cid && text)
        {
            if (prefix == true)
            {
                text = this.username + '@' + this.pcname + ':~$ ' + text;
            }
            else if (cmdName)
            {
                text = cmdName + ': ' + text;
            }
            var con = document.getElementById(this.cid);
            con.innerHTML = con.innerHTML + text + '<br>';
        }
    }
   
    makeCommand (cmd)
    {
        if (cmd && cmd != '' && this.commandsList)
        {
            cmd = (cmd.replace('<', '&lt;')).replace('>', '&rt;');
            if (this.commandsList[cmd])
            {
                console.log('Executing ' + cmd);
                this.commandsList[cmd]();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here a more in depth look at `var that = this` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises because, unfortunately in js if you define a function inside another function, "this" would not point to the outer scope, it would instead point to the global object, if you are working on a browser "this" will be the "window" object. Consider the following example, the first console.log would print `{ foo: 'bar', log: [Function] }`, it points to the right object, but the second nested function getThis console.log would point to the global object,

```
var object = {
    foo: 'bar',

    log: function() {
        console.log("this:", this);

        var getThis = function() {
            console.log("this: ", this);
        };

        getThis();
    }
};

object.log();
```

to avoid this behavior in js

you can declare a variable var self = this; and use that self throughout your code, I would say this is a good practice

```
var object = {
    foo: 'bar',

    log: function() {
        console.log("this:", this);

        var self = this;
        var getThis = function() {
            console.log("this: ", self);
        };

        getThis();
    }
};

object.log();
```

or you can bind "this" to the function like

```
var object = {
    foo: 'bar',

    log: function() {
        console.log("this:", this);

        var getThis = function() {
            console.log("this: ", this);
        }.bind(this);

        getThis();
    }
};

object.log();
```