# Updated list when var (array) changes

Tags: vue.js

I have a list of items, which I want to update when I update the array. This is my list of items:

```
<li v-for="page in pages" class="menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link" @click="currentPage = page.id">{{ page.title }}</a>
</li>
```

I have a variable which is an array:

```
data: {
    pages: [],
    menuVisible: false
},
```

I have a watch set up which updates the variable when required:

```
watch: {
  'menuVisible': function(val, oldVal) {
    $.getJSON('/pages/json/list.json', function(json){
      this.pages = json;
    });
  }
}
```

When "menuVisible" updates, it fires this, and the var changes, but the list does not.

To give a basic idea of what I am trying to achieve; I have a list of pages. A new page is created via a ajax submit. When the user opens the menu with the list of pages, it updates `menuVisible`, which in turn updates the variable. I want it to update the list of pages, but it does not.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a scope issue, `this.pages` is inside an anonomous function where the context of `this` is the function itself, not the Vue instance. To avoid this you can either use an arrow function if you are able to us `ES6` (it does require something like `babel` to compile for use in a browser):

```
watch: {
  'menuVisible': function(val, oldVal) {
    $.getJSON('/pages/json/list.json', (json) => {
      this.pages = json;
    });
  }
}
```

Or you just need to set a variable pointing to `this` outside the ajax request:

```
watch: {
  'menuVisible': function(val, oldVal) {
    var self = this; // set self to 'this'

    $.getJSON('/pages/json/list.json', function(json){
      self.pages = json;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thank man! I am already running babel (In a rails project), so it fit in straight away.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the binding of `this` in your JSON response handler.

`this.pages` inside `function(json) {..}` is not the same as `this.pages` of Vue component. `function() {..}` creates a separate context inside the curly braces. Therefore, your `pages` array is not getting updated.

You can also verify the above using [Vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools)

To resolve this bug, please change your watch function as follows:

```
watch: {
  'menuVisible': function(val, oldVal) {
    $.getJSON('/pages/json/list.json', json => {
      this.pages = json;
    });
  }
}
```

In line 3 of the above function, you can notice that now it uses something called [**arrow function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). The arrow function syntax ensures that your `this` in the outerscope (Vue component) is the same as the `this` of your JSON response handler function.

Alternatively you may also do `var that = this` outside json response handler, and set `that.pages` inside the JSON response handler. Ref: [What does 'var that = this;' mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript)