# How to access state inside function which is inside of function inside of map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make onClick effect on every item of .map method like this:

`this.props.products.map(function(item, i) {
                return (
                  <tr key={ i } onClick={ function() {
                      console.log(arrayForOnClick)
                      arrayForOnClick = [item['id'], item['name'], item['price']]
                      this.handleTableString(item['id'], item['name'], item['price'])
                      // Нужно передать айди, имя и цену в модальное окно при клике на этот <tr>. 
                    } }>
                    <td>{ item['id'] }</td>
                    <td>{ item['name'] }</td>
                    <td>{ item['price'] }</td>
                  </tr>
                )
              }, this)`

And I'm trying to access this.handleTableString which is

`handleTableString(id, name, price) {
    this.setState({
      editProductModal: true,
      selectedId: id,
      selectedName: name,
      selectedPrice: price
    })
    console.log('triggered')
  }`

But I get error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleTableString' of null`
Is there another way to make that onClick or something is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is different for each `function` (it is not preserved for your nested function). You may.

1. Use variable to keep reference on `this`.

.

```
this.props.products.map(function(item, i) {

  const self = this;
  return (
    <tr key={ i } onClick={ function() {
        console.log(arrayForOnClick)
        arrayForOnClick = [item['id'], item['name'], item['price']]
        self.handleTableString(item['id'], item['name'], item['price'])
        // Нужно передать айди, имя и цену в модальное окно при клике на этот <tr>. 
      } }>
      <td>{ item['id'] }</td>
      <td>{ item['name'] }</td>
      <td>{ item['price'] }</td>
    </tr>
  )
}, this)
```

2. Use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that don't bind `this`, so it is looked up in parent context.

.

```
this.props.products.map(function(item, i) {
  return (
    <tr key={ i } onClick={ () => {
        console.log(arrayForOnClick)
        arrayForOnClick = [item['id'], item['name'], item['price']]
        this.handleTableString(item['id'], item['name'], item['price'])
        // Нужно передать айди, имя и цену в модальное окно при клике на этот <tr>. 
      } }>
      <td>{ item['id'] }</td>
      <td>{ item['name'] }</td>
      <td>{ item['price'] }</td>
    </tr>
  )
}, this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create anonymous function like you are doing without binding context properly. It's cleaner to use arrow function in this case too:

```
this.props.products.map(function(item, i) {
  return (
    <tr key={ i } onClick={() => {
        const arrayForOnClick = [item['id'], item['name'], item['price']]
        this.handleTableString(item['id'], item['name'], item['price'])
      } }>
      <td>{ item['id'] }</td>
      <td>{ item['name'] }</td>
      <td>{ item['price'] }</td>
    </tr>
  )
}, this)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this` is null inside your `onClick` inline function. So you need to assign `onClick` to a function that `this` has been explicitly set using javascript `bind` method.

```
<tr key={ i } onClick={
  function() {
    console.log(arrayForOnClick)
    arrayForOnClick = [item['id'], item['name'], item['price']]
    this.handleTableString(item['id'], item['name'], item['price'])
  }.bind(this)
}>
...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript `this` inside function can be bound to [god-know-what](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), depending on how it was called. In your code `this` in line `this.handleTableString(item['id'], ...` is not pointing to the component.

Use ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as your handlers both for `map` and `onClick` or use [this-that trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript) in case you forced to use ES5 syntax and can't/don't want to use transpilers ([Babel](http://babeljs.io), obviously).