# Third party library is binding callbacks, but I need to access class properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, es6-class

I've seen several questions about using "this" in classes and functions, but I don't think I've seen what I'm looking for in particular.

My situation is:

I'm calling a function from a third-party library in a class method.  However, the third-party library function is calling callback.bind(this), and I need to have access to the context it's binding.

But I also want to be able to access class properties.  Is this possible? 
 If not, what are some potential workaround?  Code outline looks something like:

```
class MyClass {
  myProperty = 'something';

  myMethod() {
    console.log(this.myProperty);
  }

  otherMethod() {
     thirdPartyLibrary.functionRequiringCallback(function() {
       this.MyMethod(); //undefined
       this.requiredThirdPartyFunction(); //"this" refers to thirdPartyLibrary
     });
  }
}
```

I could certainly make the callback an arrow function so that "this" refers to the class-scope, but then I won't have access to "requiredThirdPartyFunction".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want a reference to your instance `this`, you can always use the old [`that = this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript) assignment. You assign `this` to a variable in the scope (`that` usually), and then you can reference it inside the callback.

```
otherMethod() {
  const that = this; // set a reference to the instance this

  thirdPartyLibrary.functionRequiringCallback(function() {
    that.MyMethod(); // that refers to your class instance this
    this.requiredThirdPartyFunction(); //"this" refers to thirdPartyLibrary
  });
}
```

Another option is to bind `myMethod`, by using an arrow function or Function#bind, and then assign the bound method to a variable:

```
class MyClass {
  myProperty = 'something';

  myMethod = () => console.log(this.myProperty);

  otherMethod() {
     const myMethod = this.myMethod; // assign the bound method to a variable

     thirdPartyLibrary.functionRequiringCallback(function() {
       MyMethod(); // will be invoked with original this
       this.requiredThirdPartyFunction(); //"this" refers to thirdPartyLibrary
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this did it for me.  Which means my question was basically a duplicate of all the other similar questions...thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

There are not so many options here. Since there is only one `this`, it can be either lexical:

```
  otherMethod() {
     thirdPartyLibrary.functionRequiringCallback(() => {
       this.MyMethod();
       thirdPartyLibrary.requiredThirdPartyFunction();
     });
  }
```

Or dynamic:

```
  otherMethod() {
     const _this = this;
     thirdPartyLibrary.functionRequiringCallback(function() {
       _this.MyMethod();
       this.requiredThirdPartyFunction();
     });
  }
```

The first option is more readable and is likely a better choice, since it's not obvious from the code above that `this === thirdPartyLibrary` inside callback.