# getting error "property does not exist"

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic2

I modified my question to be more specific. now i don't care about the desired behavior and i just need to correct syntax error

I was studying [this tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-cordova-sqlite-barcode-scanner-product-inventory-manager-part-3/) I face with an error in this code.

severity: 'Error'

message: 'Property 'offset' does not exist on type 'PagerserviceProvider'.'

actually i have the same error for this three variables.

> that.pageSize,that.offset,that.size

```
public async getPager(tableName:string,pageSize: number = 10) {
let pageSize = pageSize;
let offset = 0;
let limit = pageSize;
let size = await this.getTotal(tableName);
let that = this;
return  {
        initialPage:function(){

            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                var d = [];
                that.executeSql(tableName,limit,offset).then((data)=>{
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    for(var i = 0 ; i < data.rows.length ; i++)
                    {
                        d.push(data.rows.item(i));
                    }
                    resolve(d);
                },(e)=>{
                    reject(e);
                });
            });

        },
        nextPage:function(){
            if(that.offset <= that.size - that.pageSize )
            {  
                that.offset +=  that.pageSize;
            }
            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                var d = [];
                that.executeSql(tableName,limit,offset).then((data)=>{
                    for(var i = 0 ; i < data.rows.length ; i++)
                    {
                        d.push(data.rows.item(i));
                    }
                    resolve(d);
                },(e)=>{
                    reject(e);
                });
            });                    
        }            
    };}
```

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4886696/8349557. It gives a good understanding about your question Hope it helps!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does 'var that = this;' mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: @Jeremy Thille I have an error on my variable not recognise that I guess the reason is choosing the right context

Comment: actually what can I do to correct error

Comment: What exactly is the error?!

Comment: @deceze: i had an error message that  'Property 'offset' does not exist on type 'PagerserviceProvider'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the keyword `function` to declare a function, the function's this does not refer to the upper `this`. so using `this` in the function body, refers to the function itself.

The problem you are facing is related to the fact that your function is declared inside a class which already have a `this` defined, so you need a way to reference the upper `this` while being inside the nested function.

```
class Test {

  hello () { console.log('hello') }

  method () {
    this.hello() // It will work because `this` refers to the class
    function sayHello () {
      return this.hello()
      // it won't work because `this` refers to the function sayHello
    }
    return sayHello()
  }
}
```

To bypass this limitation, you can save your upper `this` in a variable while your code is in the upper scope. This variable is usually called `that` or `self`.

```
class Test {

  hello () { console.log('hello') }

  method () {
    var that = this // that is now refering to the class
    this.hello() // It will work because `this` refers to the class
    function sayHello () {
      return that.hello()
      // that is still refering to the class so it will succeed
    }
    return sayHello()
  }
}
```

EDIT:

another trick to avoid using `that` is to use ES6 arrow function. Inside an arrow function, `this` alway refers to the upper scope.

```
class Test {

  hello () { console.log('hello') }

  method () {
    this.hello() // It will work because `this` refers to the class
    // `this` refers to the upper scope by default so it works
    const sayHello = () => this.hello()
    return sayHello()
  }
}
```

EDIT 2:

Your code should be:

```
  public async getPager(tableName: string, pageSize: number = 10) {
    let pageSize = pageSize;
    let offset = 0;
    let limit = pageSize;
    let size = await this.getTotal(tableName);
    let that = this;
    return  {
        initialPage: function () {

            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                var d = [];
                that.executeSql(tableName, limit, offset).then(data => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    for(var i = 0 ; i < data.rows.length ; i++) {
                        d.push(data.rows.item(i));
                    }
                    resolve(d);
                }, e => {
                    reject(e);
                });
            });

        },
        nextPage: function () {
            if(offset <= size - pageSize ) {  
                offset += pageSize;
                // no need to use `that` because you used `let`
            }
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var d = [];
                that.executeSql(tableName, limit, offset).then(data => {
                    for(var i = 0 ; i < data.rows.length ; i++) {
                        d.push(data.rows.item(i));
                    }
                    resolve(d);
                }, e => {
                    reject(e);
                });
            });                    
        }            
      };
    }
```

Comment: I knew all but why my code have error ,I used the same rule as you said

Comment: have you explicitly declare `that.offset = ..., that.pageSize = ...` ? `let` does not add it into `that` by default

Comment: i used "var" but still i have error

Comment: try: `this.offset = 0; this.pageSize = pageSize` just before `let that = this`

Comment: i did this.offset but i get error that property does not exist,

Comment: I have edited my answer with your code

Comment: Tell me if it works

Comment: @ Guillaume Badi yeah errors are disapeared ,but what was problem?

Comment: Ok, so when you use `let` in the upper scope (the getPaper scope), you can reference your variables without `this` or `that`, because they are available for all the nested functions. If you want to access those variables in other methods, you can, instead of using `let` use `this`: `let offset = 0` becomes `this.offset = 0`

Comment: Thanks a lot very helpful to me

Comment: Cool ! Please accept the answer if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: yeah ,i already upvoted you

Answer (score 0):

'that' is just the name of a variable used to store the original value of 'this' at the start of your code, as the value of 'this' changes. The variable name could just as easily be 'dog' or 'apple'.

You might choose to use 'this' later on in your code instead if you intend to access the current value of 'this' at that point in time. Otherwise you will probably reference your original variable that stored it's value, e.g. 'that', 'dog' or 'apple'.

Comment: what I cant understand is ,I define the variable in the same context as the context I define "that" so "that.offset" is no meaningless

Answer (score 0):

`getPager` is a method: If you call it with an already lost context, `that` will get the current `this` value, which is not pointing the correct context.

```
const someInstance = new SomeClass()

someInstance.getPager() // You call getPager directly from the someInstance context

someHTMLButton.onClick = someInstance.getPager // Here the getPager method lost its context
```

A solution is to bind `getPager` to `someInstance`. This way it will always have its context `this` pointing to `someInstance`.

```
someHTMLButton.onClick = someInstance.getPager.bind(someInstance)
```