# Passing this to window.onscroll function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this

How can I pass `this` to a function assigned to my `window.onscroll` event?

I am trying to trigger `myFunction()` when a certain condition is met. I need to check this condition `onscroll`

```
  init() {
    window.onscroll = function() {
      if(this.currentItemCount() > this.totalElements){
        this.totalElements = this.currentItemCount();
        this.myFunction();
      }
    };
  }
```

However I get an error that `this.currentItemCount()` is not a function. I know that I need to pass `this` to `window.onscroll` but I cannot figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: Using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) sounds like the way to go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `that = this` construct. ([What does 'var that = this;' mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript))

```
init() {
    var that = this;
    window.onscroll = function() {
      if(that.currentItemCount() > that.totalElements){
        that.totalElements = that.currentItemCount();
        that.myFunction();
      }
    };
  }
```

Or even better use *arrow function* which preserves `this` from the wrapping context (ES6 support or transpiler required):

```
init() {
    window.onscroll = () => {
      if(this.currentItemCount() > this.totalElements){
        this.totalElements = this.currentItemCount();
        this.myFunction();
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, the arrow function is the syntax I was aiming for, just couldn't get it quite right.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
init() {
    var self = this;
    window.onscroll = function() {
      if(self.currentItemCount() > self.totalElements){
        self.totalElements = self.currentItemCount();
        self.myFunction();
      }
    };
  }
```

`this` isn't available from the inner scope, but `self` will be available.