# React event binding inside loop is undefined

Tags: reactjs, loops, events, binding, render

I add a click event inside loop of my react render method before return and the code as it follows

```
renderedCheckboxes = content.map( function(f, i) {
                if ( f['acf_fc_layout'] === 'checkbox' ) {
                    let id="customCheck" + i;
                    return (
                        <li className="list-group-item" key={i}>
                        <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name={f.checkbox} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this) } className="custom-control-input" id={id} />
                            <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor={id}>{f.label}</label>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                    )
                }
            });
```

but as I click on checkbox I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined`

What I do wrong in this case?

Comment: I susprect `this.handleClick` does not exists within the context of the map function. Cache this by writing `const that = this;` before the map function and use `that.handleClick`

Comment: thanks! that was the problem was out of scope because map function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript The accepted method is described as a hack that can be avoided by arrow functions. It will work, but is not the best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `this.handleClick` does not exists within the scrope of the map function. Cache this by writing `const that = this;` before the map function and use `that.handleClick`

Answer (score 0):

Change to arrow function so that `this` is in scope:

```
renderedCheckboxes = content.map((f, i) => {
  if ( f['acf_fc_layout'] === 'checkbox' ) {
    let id="customCheck" + i;
    return (
      <li className="list-group-item" key={i}>
        <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name={f.checkbox} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this) } className="custom-control-input" id={id} />
          <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor={id}>{f.label}</label>
        </div>
      </li>
    )
  }
});
```