# Javascript getElementById and addEventListener equivalent for Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

I need to rewrite/adapt a JS method so I can run an *old* JS script into a new Angular app.

```
  boot: function() {
    var that = this;

    that.container = document.getElementById('embedded_messenger');
    that.chatClient = document.getElementById('chat_client').contentWindow;

    window.addEventListener('message', that.receiveMessage, false);

    return this;
  }
```

Usually, this boot method is called just after the script has been loaded into the HTML page.

```
<body>
  ...
  <script src="embed.js"></script>
  <script>
      var options = {};
      Chat.boot();
  </script>
</body>
```

1. In an Angular app, should I call the boot function inside `ngOnInit()` to get the same behaviour as previously with the HTML document ?
2. `var that = this` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886632/what-does-var-that-this-mean-in-javascript) but my question is about `return this;` : is `that` returned ? Is `that` a clone of (or a reference to) `this` ?
3. `that.container = document.getElementById('embedded_messenger');` generates an error during Angular compilation :
   *Property 'container' does not exist*

Is it a good practice to use `@ViewChild('embedded_messenger')` to replace `getElementById('embedded_messenger')` or is it better to use [Angular elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) ?

4. Same question about `addEventListener` : should I use Angular [EventManager](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/EventManager) to replace it ?

Many thanks for your advices.

Comment: Just so we understand: is this old code that you don't have access to, or is this old code that you can rewrite just fine? As for (2) `that` is just a variable that has nothing to do with what's being returned, in the same way that `a` in `let a = b; ...; return b;` is irrelevant to the return.

Comment: checkout this article https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/four-ways-of-listening-to-dom-events-in-angular-part-2-hostlistener-1b66d45b3e3d

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your answer. The *old code* in the embed.js script works fine when added inside a <script> tag inside a regular html file. And I have full access to it. My problem is that I can not just add it in the Angular .html template in order to run it (I tried). So I have to rewrite to corresponding Angular .ts in order to make it work again in my Angular component.

Comment: yes viewChild is the good practice also is similar to getElementById() in code js, you can use  HostListener for DOM event listening, also you can use boot method inside ngOnInit or at any of the required moment when you want to call angular it has few more lifecycle hooks  check them too.

Comment: About (2) : `var that = this` we assign the object `this` to `that` so it is the reference to the original objet `this` that is copied. So when `that` is modified, `this` is also modified. We actually return `this` but it has been modified when `that` has been modified.

Comment: I managed to adapt the old script to make it work with Angular. However, I would like to improve my understanding : (A) when are `@ViewChild` available in the component lifecycle ? (according to my tests, they are available inside `ngAfterViewInit`. (B) About the `@HostListener('window:message', ['$event'])` : at what moment is it enabled in the component lifecycle ? (C) Is there any documentation so I can understand ['$event'] args possibilities ? Thank you.