# Question about create object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've learned that you can create your own 'class' in this way:

```
function Person(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age  = age;
}

Person.prototype.foo = function(){
    // do something
}

Person.prototype.foo2 = function(){
    // do something
}

var wong2 = new Person("wong2", "20");
```

Now if `foo` and `foo2` both need to call another function named `foo3`, where should I add it to?
I don't want `foo3` to be called by `wong2`, so I can't just use

```
Person.prototype.foo3 = function(){
    // something else else
}
```

But if I define it in the global scope, I don't think it's very nice. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain "I don't want foo3 to be called by wong2" ? I thought the whole point was that foo3() is going to be called by the methods of Person which, of course, wong2 has.

Comment: @Ernest `wong2.foo1()` and `wong2.foo2()` can call `foo3`, but no `wong2.foo3`, can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define foo3 inside a closure that foo1 and foo2 have access to, something like

```
function() {
    function foo3() { ... }
    Person.prototype.foo = function(){
       foo3();
    }

    ...

}();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611/javascript-private-methods) SO question and article about [Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but this acts as a static function.

```
Person.foo3 = function() {
    // something else else else but not inherited by wong2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not create your own namespace? try

```
var person = {}; 
person.createPerson=function (name,age){
   this.name=name; 
   this.age=age; 
   if (age<18){
     this.status = 'cannot Marry';
   }else{
     person.addMarriageStatus('married');
   }
}
person.addMarriageStatus = function(status){this.status=status};
person.createPerson('Jack',2);
//person
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression you want something like a static function, where `foo3` belongs to `Person`, but not to `wong2` and certainly not to the global scope.

If so, just assign a function to `Person.foo3` as i have below.

http://jsfiddle.net/audLd/1/

```
function Person(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age  = age;       
}

Person.foo3 = function() {return 10;};

Person.prototype.foo = function(){
    return Person.foo3();
}

Person.prototype.foo2 = function(){
    return Person.foo3()*2;
}

var wong2 = new Person("wong2", "20");

alert("" + wong2.foo() + ", " + wong2.foo2()); //works

alert("" + Person.foo3()); //works.  this is the distinction between what I'm loosely calling static and private

alert(foo3()); //doesnt work
alert(wong2.foo3()); //doesnt work
```

If you want a 'private' member thru closures then that is an entirely different animal.