# How does the skeleton of jQuery work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been programming in JavaScript for a couple of years, but I've never understood *how* different techniques work in JavaScript, only *that* it works..

Now, after learning properly how prototypes and constructors work, I took a look at jQuery to learn something before I set out to make my own (not publicly accessible) plugin for my own website.

The problem is just that I don't understand how it works. Here is a almost working sample: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3zWvR/1/

```
(function() {
    test = function(selector) {
        return new test.prototype.init(selector);
    }
    test.prototype = {
        init: function(selector) {
            alert("init ran");
            if (!arguments[0]) {
                return this;
            }
        }
    }
 // As I understand the jQuery code, the next line should really be
 // test.prototype = {
    test.prototype.init.prototype = {
        send: function() {
            alert("send ran");
        }
    }

    window.ob = test;
})()

ob().send();​
```

I've commented a line in there that shows what I think really should be there if I do it like jQuery. But I'm not able to replicate it so that you could do ob.method() either...

How is the jQuery "framework" or skeleton built and how does it work?

Comment: you of all should know the answer to this: it's magic!

Comment: @Abhilash You wouldn't believe me if I told you how many have made jokes about my nickname! xD

Comment: You might be interested in this: [Paul Irish on jQuery](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpaulirish.com%2F2010%2F10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source%2F&ei=aICsUNTJBbHciQKD8YHQCw&usg=AFQjCNGdORx-aMY9iSzUuF-5SqUnymJP4A&sig2=XFQvBDlkywL8QdC-sjpdWA)

Comment: And this is a really good tutorial on advanced javascript (from the creator of jQuery) [advanced javascript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/)

Comment: @Sdedelbrock the video is very useful, but he says nothing about this issue

Answer (score 3):

Well, your question is very interesting, and it's something that has been on my head since I started to look at the source code of jQuery. Your code should work as you wanted to if you add this:

```
test.prototype.init.prototype = test.prototype;
test.send = test.prototype.send = function(){
  alert("send ran");
};
```

instead of this:

```
test.prototype.init.prototype = {
  send: function() {
    alert("send ran");
  }
};
```

You are probably saying "I already know that, you are just adding the method `send()` to the `test` object and to the prototype of itself", but doing it this way, you are doing exactly what you want: make that `ob`, `ob()` and all the variables created with it, like `var somevar = ob()` have the method `send()`.

If you take a look at the jQuery source code, they use the method `extend()` to extend the jQuery object. Looking at some of the `.extend()` calls, you will see that if one method/property is added only to the `jQuery.fn` object (that is a shorthand to the `prototype`), the `jQuery` object doesn't have that method/property. You can see this if you type in a console `jQuery.off`, it will return `undefined`, but the method `off` exists in the `jQuery.fn` object (type `jQuery.fn.off` in a console and you will see it).

If you think in `jQuery`, when you write a plugin, you start by doing `jQuery.fn.plugin =`, so you add your plugin to the objects created by `jQuery`, but your plugin is not accessible directly from `jQuery`.

Think of `jQuery` as a constructor that also has a lot of utilities. The object returned when you do `$(selector)` have all the methods in `jQuery.fn` but not all of the `jQuery` object, only the ones that they have added into the `jQuery.fn`.

Comment: @Jordi I'm sure you will be there the next time to point it if I fail again.

Comment: This is a great answer! Do you know how they've implemented private functions as well? So they can be called from the inside, but not from the outside?

Comment: And is the extend-method adding the new methods to both the jQuery object and to the jQuery.prototype.init object?

Comment: It's not private, it's the same case as when you add something to te `String` object, i.e `String.prototype.returnTrue = function(){return "true"};`, the function is accessible in all the string objects, but not in the `String` object

Comment: No, if you look at the code, you will see some `jQuery.extend(...` and some `jQuery.fn.extend(...`. If I'm not wrong, the `jQuery.fn.init` is just the real constructor of all `jQuery` objects, and they added the line `jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn` to make all `jQuery` objects be instances of `jQuery` itself.

Comment: Oh, I mean, jQuery has lots of methods that aren't callable via $.privateMethod(). Do you know how that is implemented? Is this: http://jsfiddle.net/3zWvR/2/ how jQuery in a simplified form is implementing it?

Comment: But they are callable via jQuery.privateMethod() or similar inside the closure.

Comment: Are they really doing this just to enable us to use $.ajax() instead of $().ajax()?

Comment: The `ajax` method is only available in the `jQuery` (or $) object. If you try to do `$(selector).ajax` it returns `undefined`. You have to think of `jQuery` as an object with a set of methods and properies, that also is a constructor, and the objects returned by that constructor have another set of methods and properties, but different from the `jQuery` ones. Maybe some of the methods in `jQuery` are accessible in the constructed objects, but to achieve that, the developers had to extend the prototype of `jQuery` to expose those methods to the constructed objects

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to learn something from this to apply to my own JS-code. Do you know how one can have private methods? The jQuery approach is a bit overwhelming for 10 small plugins I'm writing.. And the jQuery approach I see now is made to allow the plugin to differenciate between $.method() and $().method()..

Comment: If you are interested in private methods in javascript, i recomend you [this page](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) from Crockford's page and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611/javascript-private-methods) on Stack Overflow, they are very well explained. Hope it helps :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19935/discussion-between-victor-and-student-of-hogwarts)