# How to access from 'private method' to 'public variable', in Javascript class

Tags: javascript, html

First, See my code plz.

```
function test(){

    this.item = 'string';

    this.exec = function(){
        something();
    }

    function something(){
        console.log(this.item);
        console.log('string');
    }
}
```

And I made class and call 'exec function', like this code

```
var t = new test();

t.exec();
```

But result is...

```
undefined
string
```

I wanna access from something function to test.item.

Have you any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `something` with [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) so that `this` is properly set inside of `something`:

```
function test(){

    this.item = 'string';

    this.exec = function(){
        something.apply(this);
    }

    function something(){
        console.log(this.item);
        console.log('string');
    }
}
```

As @aaronfay pointed out, this happens because `this` doesn't refer to the object that `new test()` created.  You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), but the general rule is:

If a function is invoked on an `object`, then `this` refers to that `object`.  If a function is invoked on its own (as is the case in your code), then `this` refers to the global object, which in the browser is `window`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `function something() {}` alters the context of the `this` keyword, and that's why it's no longer as expected. `apply` effectively "applies" the context of `this` to another function.

Answer (score 2):

You have many choices, but I recommend the last one.

```
var item = 'string'
```

or

```
this.exec = function(){
    something.apply(this, []);
}
```

or

```
var that = this;
function something(){
    console.log(that.item);
    console.log('string');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`this.item` in `something()` isn't what you think it is.

The `this` value is different. In this case, it's the global object.

The best solution, in my opinion, is to declare a variable with a reference to `this`, that can be accessed inside the inner function.

---

```
function test() {
    var that = this; // a reference to 'this'

    function something() {
        console.log(that.item); // using the outer 'this'
        console.log('string');
    }

    this.item = 'string';

    this.exec = function(){
        something();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I Know. That have another scope, yes. But, I don't want use like 'var that = this;'. Anyway, Thanks to your answer! @Joe Simmons

Comment: You're welcome. I will say that using `var that = this;` is much more dynamic and easy to type in big applications. I'm the creator of a JS library similar to jQuery, so I know that.

Comment: That was very helpful. I'll use that at next project! Thanks again! @Joe Simmons

Comment: You're welcome. PM me if you have any problems with your project :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just define something like this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vSAje/)

```
function test(){

    this.item = 'string';

    this.exec = function(){
        this.something();
    }

    this.something = function(){
        console.log(this.item);
        console.log('string');
    }
} 

var t = new test();
t.exec();
// output:
// string 
// string
```

Comment: That reason is I want use private function

Comment: take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611/javascript-private-methods  for JS private methods.