# private method in an javascript object

Tags: javascript, oop, object, private

I've an object looks like this:

```
var obj ={

  property : '',
  myfunction1 : function(parameter){
     //do stuff here
  }
}
```

I need to set some private properties and functions, which can not be accessed/seen from outside of the object. It is not working with
`var property:,` or `var myFunction1`

Next question is, if I call a function within or outside the object, I always have to do this with `obj.myfunction()`. I would like to asign "this" to a variable. Like `self : this`. and call inside the object my functions and variables with `self.property` and `self.myfunction`.

How? :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. In short: If dou define a function inside another function, your inner function will be private, as long as you will not provide any reference to if.

```
(function obj(){
    var privateMethod = function() {};
    var publicMethod = function() {
        privateMethod();
        ...
    };

    return {
        pubMethod: publicMethod
    }
}());
```

Comment: This link could help you later on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611/javascript-private-methods

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = (function() {
  var privateProperty;
  var privateFunction = function(value) {
    if (value === void 0) {
      return privateProperty;
    } else {
      privateProperty = value;
    }
  };
  var publicMethod = function(value) {
    return privateFunction(value);
  }

  return {
    getPrivateProperty: function() {
      return privateFunction();
    },
    setPrivateProperty: function(value) {
      privateFunction(value);
    }
  }
})();

obj.setPrivateProperty(3);
console.log(obj.getPrivateProperty());
// => 3
console.log(obj.privateProperty);
// => undefined
obj.privateFunction();
// => TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use closures. JavaScript has [function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet), so you have to use a function.

```
var obj = function () {
    var privateVariable = "test";
    function privateFunction() {
        return privateVariable;
    }

    return {
        publicFunction: function() { return privateFunction(); }
    };
}();
```