# Can we achieve encapsulation in Object literals in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

We know when we are using **Object Literals** or when we employ **Object.Create()** to inherit a new Object of a parent one, the child object inherit all the properties and functions of the parent object.

So, how we can hide the private members form the inherited class?

So if we can't, it means using **function** as **class** and the "**new**" keyword to inherit from the parent class, is the only way to reach the **ENCAPSULATION** in JavaScript!

Comment: *"how we can hide the private members"* There are no private members (properties I assume) in JavaScript. Could you provide an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: Encapsulation can be done through closures in JS.

Comment: @Felix Kling of course we have and we should have! This is very obvious! We can use scopes and "var" in a scope to have private members!

Comment: @Amir: Of course, but what does this have to do with object literals?

Comment: Up through current published standards (ES 5.1), there is no way to have a private property on an object. Though, going forward, [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) are being introduced in ECMAScript 6 to support the idea. Accessing the property requires using the same Symbol.

Comment: @Felix Kling Object literals have some properties. How we can make a property private in an object literal?

Comment: @Amir: You can't. That was the point of my comment. There are no private properties. There are no "private members". What you are referring to is using closures to encapsulate data. I wouldn't call that "private members".

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript private methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611/javascript-private-methods)

Comment: @Jonathan: You can still iterate over all the properties of the object, whether symbol or not.

Comment: @ Jarrod Roberson this is totally a different question with the "JavaScript private methods" discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No.  All properties in Object literals are public (at least as of [ES5](https://es5.github.io/)).

That said, thanks to [lexical scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope), Encapsulation **does** exist in Javascript, and can be achieved through the use of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

For example, the object returned by `myObjectWithPrivateMembers` has access to an encapsulated property, `value`, which is not publicly visible/accessible (because that object is defined within a closure).

```
function myObjectWithPrivateMembers() {
    var value = 1;
    var addOne = function() {
        value++; 
    };
    var getValue = function() {
        return value;
    };
    return {
        addOne: addOne,
        getValue: getValue
    };
}

var test = myObjectWithPrivateMembers();
test.value;  // undefined
test.getValue();  // 1
test.addOne();
test.getValue();  // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to obtain encapsulation are functions or anonymous functions (closures). This is an example of information hiding and getter/setter logic while classical JS (not ES6/Harmony) does not *apparently* support it:

```
var obj = (function () {
  var hidden;

  hidden = 1973;

  return {
    "get": function () { return hidden; },
    "set": function (v) { hidden = v; }
  };
}()); // define and execute right away
```

You can now use `obj` as follows:

```
obj.get()       // returns the hidden value
obj.set(1982)   // sets the hidden value
```

Demonstration of information hiding:

```
obj.hidden      // no dice
```

> OO programming in JS does not really support classical inheritance.
>   It supports prototypical inheritance which has its differences.

Comment: I already said I know this. I want to know is it possible to achieve Encapsulation in Object literals?

Comment: Ah ok :) well... I think the comments do already answer very well what is going on with ES5 and ES6...

Comment: I know prototype inheritance and classical inheritance. I am trying to say, In some articles we see that they are trying to bring the class oriented concepts into Object Oriented (let's say prototypal oriented). I can just quote this amazing paragraph from "you don't know JS" book : "I believe the label "prototypal inheritance" itself (and trying to mis-apply all its associated class-orientation terminology, like "class", "constructor", "instance", "polymorphism", etc) has done more harm than good in explaining how JavaScript's mechanism really works."

Comment: You're right, it did more harm than good. Especially the *bible* by Flanagan was outright misleading up to the 5th edition. We had to wait for Crockford's "Good Parts" to see how well OO pattern really play out without classes. There are many mediocre JS books. Just don't waste time on those :)