# Can we return document.createElement("element")?

Tags: javascript

I have to create an input box multiple times, so I call a function like this multiple times:

```
function __createInputBox(id) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");

    input.setAttribute('id', id);
    input.setAttribute('type', 'number');
    input.setAttribute('name', id);
    input.setAttribute('value', '0');
    input.setAttribute('min', '0');

    return input;
}
```

In my main function, I append it as such:

```
var box = __createInputBox(id);
element.appendChild(box);
```

I keep getting this error:

```
__createInputBox is not defined
```

So are we allowed to return the value from document.createElement("element")? If its bad to do so, what is the better way to add multiple elements to the page?

This how I declare the function:

```
function InputSpace(){
this.inputSpace = document.getElementById("inputspace");
this.num = 1;

    function __createInputBox(id) {
       // function  declared here
    }
```

This is the code where I call it:

```
InputSpace.prototype = {
constructor: InputSpace,
drawInputSpace : function () {
  var i = 0,
      max;
  var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
  var table_body = document.createElement("TBODY");
  for(max = num; i<num; i++){
        var element = document.createElement("TR");
        var box = __createInputBox(id);
        element.appendChild(box);
        table_body.appendChild(element);
  }
  table.appendChild(table_body);
  this.inputSpace.appendChild(table);
}
```

Comment: Show us the code, this is likely a matter of scope, meaning that to the code where you're calling `__createInputBox` there is no such function

Comment: Your problem is that the function `__createInputBox` cannot be found! It has nothing to do with whatever is going on *inside* that function. Likely you're defining the function in a different scope...

Comment: __createInputBox undefined its not related to the return.... try to call it after page load

Comment: Works [just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/ff0g8ac2/)

Comment: From the simplistic example you gave it is not possible to recreate the problem you are describing - as others have said, the underlying issue is most likely *where* you are calling the function from. Is this code inside another module or inside some other structure?

Comment: @JuanCortes @Lix @deceze I just added the whole function. Could it be that `__createInputBox` is private thats why its not defined?

Comment: @Vanojx Yes, it works. After declaring it as a global function. How do we call an objects own private function then?

Comment: When not get the element with document.getElementById. If you have an id...

Comment: @user3806549 I am dynamically creating the elements. So `document.getElementById` wont have anything to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comments,  we can return `document.createElement("element")` in from a function. The reason for the `function is undefined` error, was because I was calling a function outside its scope. The proper way to call an object's private function is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55638/4570506)

Changing the code to access private functions properly:

```
function InputSpace(){
    // public attributes
    this.inputSpace = document.getElementById("inputspace");
    this.num = 1;
}

InputSpace.prototype = (function(){
     // private functions
     var __createInputBox(id){
     var input = document.createElement("input");

         input.setAttribute('id', id);
         input.setAttribute('type', 'number');
         input.setAttribute('name', id);
         input.setAttribute('value', '0');
         input.setAttribute('min', '0');

         return input;
     }; 
     return {
     constructor: InputSpace,
     // public functions
     drawInputSpace : function () {
         var i = 0,
         max;
         var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
         var table_body = document.createElement("TBODY");
         for(max = num; i<num; i++){
             var element = document.createElement("TR");
             var box = __createInputBox(id);
             element.appendChild(box);
             table_body.appendChild(element);
         }
         table.appendChild(table_body);
         this.inputSpace.appendChild(table);
    }
})();
```