# How to use "private" attributes with properties in a class?

Tags: javascript, oop

Considering the following "class" :

```
function Test()
{
    var data = new Uint8Array(232);
}
```

I would like to add the following accessor to the data attribute :

```
Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, "data",
{
    get: function()
    {
        // calculate other things related to data
        return data;
    }
});
```

I encountered the following problems :

- Defining the property inside the "class" scope works but makes each instances to redefine the property which is bad. Edit: this is where the relevancy of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611) stops.
- Defining the property outside obviously don't work since data is made private by closure.

So I tried to make the attributes public :

```
function Test2()
{
    this._data = new Uint8Array(232);
}

Object.defineProperty(Test2.prototype, "data",
{
    get: function()
    {
        // calculate other things related to data
        return this._data;
    },
    // Avoid "TypeError: setting a property that has only a getter"
    set: function(nv)
    {
        this._data = nv;
    }
});
```

Edit: I now use "_data" (instead of "data") as my private attribute to avoid a recursion problem with the "data" property. This pattern seems to work.

But is it a good and efficient pattern ? Is there a pattern that allow use of pseudo-private variables with properties ?

Comment: Do you really need to name property on the object prototype and object itself by the same name? it's causing your error

Comment: You are right. I guess I will go for the "_data" notation then.

Comment: It's an interesting question - do not close it until you get a good explanation why this happens

Comment: If you already made `.data` a public property, you don't need an extra setter at all.

Comment: @Bergi: yes I do. I don't want data to be accessed unless a certain process (a checksum calculation) is done before.

Comment: @BasileCopin, so what is your question now after your edit?

Comment: @Maximus, my question ("How to use “private” attributes with properties in a class?") remain the same. The recursion problem was related to a workaround. I'm willing to use this workaround but only if this is the best solution.

Comment: "*Is there a pattern that allow use of pseudo-private variables with properties?*" - isn't that exactly what you're already doing with `._data`?

Comment: Well as far as I know it's only private by convention that way. But I suppose it's good enough.