# How to access function inside function without outer returning inner one

Tags: javascript, function, scope, window-object

I have got a function 'alpha', and there is another function 'beta' inside it. If I don't return beta in alpha, then how to access beta. Is there anyway of doing this? (Like, I can access alpha writing window.alpha(), as in global context alpha becomes a property of window object, then how to access beta as property, via window dom tree)?

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script>

function alpha() { 
  console.log("hi");
  function beta() {
    console.log("hello");
  } 
} 
alpha(); //works 
window.alpha(); //works
beta(); //it is directly not accessible. How to access it if alpha does not return it

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

alpha() is in Window Dom but why not beta? (Even not inside alpha)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you can not do this thing either you can prefer these option but in these you have to call `alpha` once in order to get beta

//first option

```
(function alpha() { 
  console.log("hi");
  function beta() {
    console.log("hello");
  } 
  window.beta = beta;
})()
```

//second option

Use `this` to create `beta` as property in `alpha`

```
function alpha() {
  this.beta = function() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}
let alphaObject = new alpha();
alphaObject.beta();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to return `beta`, you could return `this` and define `beta` as `this.beta` :

To access `beta()`, you simply need to call `alpha().beta()`
.

```js
function alpha() {
  console.log("hi");

  this.beta = () => {
    console.log("hello");
  }

  return this;
}

alpha().beta();
```

Answer (score 2):

The beta() method is private to function alpha. The way Javascript scoping works prevents you from directly accessing the inner functions . Create it as a property of alpha by using `this.beta`

Answer (score 1):

Declare `beta` as a member of `alpha` using `this`:

```js
function alpha() {
  console.log("hi");

  this.beta = function() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}

let a = new alpha();
a.beta();
```

You current implementation prevents JavaScript from accessing `beta` from outside of `alpha`. Read more about [private functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611/javascript-private-methods) in JavaScript.

Using `this` you can actually attach such methods to the instances of the function `alpha`. That's what I've done in this solution.