# How do I make a variable private?

Tags: javascript, dom, private

How do I make the variable *balance* private, and at the same time keep the value 100.00 in the textfield?

HTML-textfield:

```
<span type="text" id="txtMyAccountBalance">&nbsp;</span>
```

Here is the function:

```
function TAccount()
  {
      this.balance = 0.0;
      this.printOut = function () {
          txtMyAccountBalance.innerText = this.balance.toFixed(2);
      }
  }

var currentAccount = new TAccount ();

currentAccount.balance = 100.0;
```

This works quite good, and the textfield shows 100.00 as the balance. How do I make the variable *balance* private? I think I have to use *var* instead of *this*, but how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Private properties in JavaScript ES6 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156326/private-properties-in-javascript-es6-classes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript private methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611/javascript-private-methods)

Answer (score 4):

In this case you can actually use `var` indeed!

```
function TAccount() {
  var balance = 0.0; // This is not accessible outside of this function, making it practically "private"

  this.printOut = function () {
    // It feels a bit weird, but here we "just" use the balance variable that is defined outside this function
    txtMyAccountBalance.innerText = balance.toFixed(2);
  }

  this.doubleBalance = function() {
    // Same way we can change it by re-assigning
    balance = balance * 2;
  }
}
```

Do not use this for security though, as it is **not secure**. People can still go in the javascript console and hack their way into the code to set it to different values. A value that is impossible to be manipulated by a user is not possible!

Comment: Thanks alot, this is almost what I was hoping for. Is it possible to keep the `var balance = 0.0;` and still get the textfield `<span type="text" id="txtMyAccountBalance">&nbsp;</span>` to show the `currentAccount.balance = 100.0;` ?

Comment: @Senseless if you define `var txtMyAccountBalance = document.querySelector('#txtMyAccountBalance');` above `function TAccount() { ... }`, it should work just like how you did it before! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Symbol syntax

```
var TAccount = (function() {

    var balanceSymbol = Symbol('balance');

    TAccount.prototype.setBalance = function(BAL) {
        this[balanceSymbol] = BAL;
    }

    TAccount.prototype.getBalance = function() {
        return this[balanceSymbol];
    }

    TAccount.prototype.printOut = function () {
        txtMyAccountBalance.innerText = this.balance.toFixed(2);
    }


});

var currentAccount = new TAccount();

currentAccount.setBalance(100.0);
console.log(currentAccount.balance); // undefined
console.log(currentAccount.getBlance()); // 100
```